# Is a "how can I do this" question OK for the site?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Is this an OK question to ask on the site? It's not exactly a "what's wrong with this code", but a "how can I do this".

> When a user starts up my app for the first time, I would like to be able to display a one-time only route for setup, in order to allow them to create an admin account and set settings (like database).
>
> A good example for this is how [WordPress's installation](http://example.com) works, which I would like to mimic in my Ruby on Rails app.
>
> Is there a way to only route to a controller action when it hasn't been routed to before, and is there in a "safe" way to set the database configuration?
>
> Is creating a separate server (Sinatra) good for this?

Comment: Hmm...I'd vote to close that question as **primarily opinion-based** or **too broad**. As too broad because OP is asking about *how can I do this* and didn't try anything. As POB because OP is asking about *Is XXX good for this?*

Comment: @KevinGuan I guess that makes sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Frankly, No, it isn't OK. I would vote to close it as *too broad*. On SO we keep asking people to ask *specific* questions which have *clear input and expected output*. We almost always expect some kind of *code* to work with. A question without proper code will usually be interpreted differently by different people which will lead to different and often incorrect answers.

I understand, some questions might require no code at all. They are usually *how to design this* or *give me the codez* questions (I am not considering spam here :P).

My suggestion : Try something, hit a road block, come back here with a specific question. *Not able to display one time setup when user starts app* **could** be an acceptable question if accompanied by proper code.