# How is this Sikuli question 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion

I've come across this question:

[Save the screenshot of desktop in Microsoft Word using Sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43647664/save-the-screenshot-of-desktop-in-microsoft-word-in-sikuli)

> I am new to Sikuli and I had one doubt. Consider I am using Sikuli and written some sentences in Microsoft Word using Sikuli (by using the editor command). Now I want to take a screenshot of the Desktop and paste in the Microsoft Word file after the sentences I have written.
>
> Can this be done in Sikuli?

It is super straightforward, had a correct and confirmed to be working answer:

> If the Word window is already in focus, just do:
>
> ```
> type(Key.PRINTSCREEN)
> type("v", KeyModifier.CTRL)
> ```

How did this get to be put on hold as 'too broad'? If that is correct I'm not getting this site -  ***at all***.

Comment: So, considering you are asking "can this be done", would the answer "yes" be satisfactory? I would surmise "yes" wouldn't be ok. You would like an actual method to do this actually. Now with that in mind, this does look like a "how do I do this?" or "give me the code" which is too broad, as we are not fixing your issue with your code here, we are giving you the full method. Ideally you come to Stack with "I want to do X with Sikuli. I tried Y.... I got Z.". (just realized this isn't YOUR question.... the point still stands :P )

Comment: So I'm missing a piece of translation. 'Not done or not included your homework'?

Comment: The cynical users here will tell you that, yes. I prefer to give the benefit of the doubt that this isn't homework, and the OP just needs to research a bit more before posting this on Stack, but the logic behind it all is the same

Comment: Much of my confusion comes from a million similar questions that escape. Getting to be put on hold seems to be the exception.

Comment: Getting down-voted also seems to be the rule.

Comment: Indeed. But the fact that some crap gets through doesn't mean it SHOULD. We are inundated with crappy questions, and oftentimes we just don't have all needed resources to close (or put them on hold) all of them.

Comment: On meta, downvotes don't cost rep so they come more liberally. In general, this isn't a new question though (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311246/is-a-how-can-i-do-this-question-ok-for-the-site, for instance). So you could get downvoted for not having searched enough. Anyway, it won't change your rep, score, or anything. As long as it's meta.

Comment: So true. Help page never gets read that is for sure.

Comment: This question was originally tagged with [java] [python] [sql].  Gets you about *everybody* to look at it, they'll have no idea what you are talking about.  Proper tagging is crucial to find the right audience for a question.

Comment: Things move fast for even one of these tags, yes. Wondering about the use of zoning for SO.

Comment: If one spams programming language tags, yes they gain attention to their question, but often it's *negative* attention, so another vote to be as specific with your tagging as possible.

Comment: @Bookeater please don't vandalise your question. You can't delete it because it has an answer and it would be unfair to the person who put in time to answer your question.

Comment: @Robert Longson, believe me, I know. I'm __very__ irritated about the way the community reacts to attempts to improve. What happened to the Sikuli question plainly was wrong, and will never be corrected. The question is NOT too broad. It was incomplete. When you click around as is, there are no pointers about how to put it right.

Answer (score 13):

Let's boil the question down to its essence and see if we arrive at the same conclusion.

> I'm new to FooToolbox and had a question.  I'm trying to *foo* the *bar* with FooToolbox.
>
> Can this be done with FooToolbox?

"Can this be done" is ***fairly*** broad.  In effect, the question is asking if this particular tool supports this particular function, which is something I'd expect one to find out by reading the tool's site.

Now instead, if they had asked the question (emphasis mine):

> I'm new to FooToolbox and had a question.  I'm trying to *foo* the *bar* with FooToolbox.
>
> **I've attempted this code, but I get this error:**
> **`BizException in FooToolbox:  unable to grok the bar`**
>
> **`FooToolbox.invoke("foo").bar()`**
>
> **How can I get this to work properly?**

*Then* we wouldn't have any broadness to it; the question is scoped very narrowly and has a specific, concise issue to it instead of a "can I do this"-style question.