# Answers that are too detailed

Tags: discussion

I'm curious how to handle answers that are on the verge of making Stack Overflow a code-writing service, something that is not the goal of this site. I know this may sound strange, but I think answers that are too thorough especially to questions that don't show much or any research effort at all are not helping the long-term health of the site.

As an example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719564/how-does-one-use-the-same-model-more-than-once-with-different-names) came up today and to me doesn't show that the OP has researched or even googled much or anything at all on how to accomplish his task.

Am I being too paranoid with this or is this a cause for concern?

I don't think this answer is a problem per se; it's just that such detailed answers to a poorly researched question encourage lazy questions.

Also, [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/308731) says that one should almost never post a question, for threats of eternal shame. A bit of an exaggeration of course, but still.

Comment: The OP may not deserve to be helped, but what about other people searching for the problem in the future? They may also find the answer helpful.

Comment: @user000001 When someone just dumps their requirements, or their broken code, and someone else just dumps some "working" code you've created something that is unlikely to be useful to anyone else, and even if it would be, is unlikely to be found by anyone else.

Comment: It's fairly broad for reasons [similar to this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348624/1079354).  The only difference between your example question and that one is that this one at least makes an *attempt* at adding code; there's no real detail on explaining *why* their code doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby on rails, but it seems like the question is reasonable, it seems to provide an expected result and a code attempt;  sometimes people don't know the technology enough to know exactly the right words to search for, and don't find what they are looking for with the terms they try and use.  That doesn't mean they don't deserve help and encouragement....

Comment: It's not even clear if the code works or doesn't work, no info at all.

Comment: @Servy well if nobody sees it again, I guess there's no harm done. On the other hand I've been receiving upvotes years later on questions that didn't seem special at the time.

Comment: sometimes the best approach is to try and edit the question or explain to the OP how to improve the question;  making a post on meta that calls the question out only serves to draw more down votes, making it more difficult for the poster.

Comment: @Claies If it gets closed it's because people think it should be closed. The op has gotten a free solution also, so not much incentive in improving the question.

Comment: Depending on how I'm feeling, I may 1) vote-to-close, 2) suggest how to solve the problem, or 3) write a complete answer which is as technically sophisticated as possible, utilizing features of the language or whatever which a beginner is probably not familiar with. (1) is when I'm feeling rushed or lazy, (2) is when I'm feeling helpful, and (3) is for other times.

Comment: @BobJarvis Yeah, that sounds about right, I guess the percentage ratio of those feelings varies a lot between people.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the answer *works*, who cares? If the author felt like sitting down and playing with the problem for a bit, who are you to say they shouldn't have posted their results?

There are folks who've put far, far more time and effort into answers, usually because the topic caught their fancy somehow and kept them entertained. Arguably, this is an area where Stack Overflow pays off more for the answerer than for the asker, providing a real-world equivalent to the sorts of artificial coding games popular elsewhere. The same author could've posted their results on a blog somewhere, to haunt the outer reaches of the 'Net until they got tired of paying for hosting and took it down... Instead, they shared it with the person who prompted them to think and - just maybe - it can live on for others' benefit.

If you think of questions as nothing more than Stack Overflow's equivalent to Wikipedia's "stub" articles - a rough placeholder prompting some knowledgeable person to add information - then worrying about [gratuitous displays of effort](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-in-general-be-awarding-as-for-effor) becomes pointless; even the most painfully overwrought question becomes uninteresting once respectable answers have been posted.

Comment: According to this question one should almost never post a question, for threats of eternal shame https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/308731. Of course it's an exaggeration, but shows a different angle

Comment: Also, something I didn't make clear enough in the question, is that the answers are not a problem per se, but just that they encourage lazy questions.

Comment: This'd be a really boring site if everyone took that to heart, eh @Iceman? Me & you hardly ever asked questions; if it wasn't for all the folks posting these "stubs", there'd be nothing to do around here. Granted, there are a lot of really boring, useless questions... But they're problematic 'cause they're boring and useless, not because they're lazy - all questions are lazy. My most popular question is self-answered, a frequent reminder that I wouldn't have had to ask it if I'd just spent a few more weeks thinking about it.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, and of course that answer is a big exaggeration.

Comment: I have 16k rep with 0 asked questions.  It definitely can be done: http://stackoverflow.com/users/2495283/claies?tab=questions.  However, I still believe that **most** questions have at least *some* value to them;  If I assume that the question is bad because it isn't something I would have asked, then every question would be bad, and the site would be empty.

Comment: As an example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830139/how-can-i-do-these-image-processing-tasks-using-opengl-es-2-0-shaders), particularly in its original form, was pretty bad and was very much in the "do my work for me" category. However, it provided the seed of an idea and I decided to have a little fun with it. The result was code that a number of people have benefited from.

Comment: I'm voting this as the answer, though I don't agree with it 100%, but that is no problem. Disagreeing in a civil way is no problem for me. I realize however that English not being my first language, I probably have not expressed my thoughts quite well enough in my post, but have hopefully not offended anyone.

Answer (score 3):

I more blame question.  I think the best remedy is to ask for clarification via a comment and immediately VTC "unclear what you are asking".  Repeat offenders I will also down vote.  If the user fixes the question then I remove the VTC.

If someone answers a vague question I don't penalize them with a down vote but I don't up vote either.

Even if I know what they want I will not bail them out with a complete answer until the question is complete.