# Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've seen many instances where someone comments on an answer that has been given to a question that was off-topic in their opinion, telling the answerer that they should not answer questions like that.

Sometimes I agree with their opinion about the question and think most others would as well, other times not so much, but I'm wondering about the constructiveness of a comment like that on an answer whether or not their assessment of the question was "correct".

I'm not including any examples because I think it seems clear enough what I'm referring to without meta-affecting anything, and I don't want the discussion to become overly focused on a specific instance. (And I'm not asking about comments on any of my own answers.)

Are those comments constructive, or just noise?

Does it matter if the question actually *is* off-topic, or are the comments on the answer constructive (or not) regardless of that?

Comment: As much as people are constantly complaining about how people don't tell them what's wrong with their bad answers when they get downvotes, they tend to complain even more when you *do* explain why the answer is a bad answer, which of course trains people to not bother.  It's not unconstructive to tell people what problems their answer has, but it's rather rarely welcome information.

Comment: @Servy Yeah, both halves of that are certainly true. But the comments I'm thinking of don't really offer any criticism of the content of the answer, but just state that it shouldn't have been provided based on the question.

Comment: But then, I guess "should not exist" could be considered a problem their answer has.

Comment: If that's *all* it says, then sure, it's not providing any relevant information.  If it explains *why*, then it's quite useful.

Comment: It most certainly *is* a problem with the answer (assuming it's a correct statement).  Posting a comment that asserts the statement without any reasoning isn't particularly helpful, in the same way that posting a comment to say that an answer is technically correct isn't helpful (without an explanation of *what* is wrong).  The main exception that comes to mind is if the question is already closed, or has lots of comments under it explaining its problems, at which point you could argue that the problems with the question are enumerated there, and don't need to be repeated.

Comment: "assuming it's a correct statement" is the main problem I have with it. Sometimes when I see comments like that, I agree with them. Other times, I think they seem misguided. I just don't know if I should flag them as not constructive based on my opinion.

Comment: If you feel that someone posts a comment that's simply *incorrect*, then that doesn't make it flag worthy.  If you feel it's important, feel free to reply with your perspective.  Someone disagreeing with you doesn't make it not constructive.

Comment: I'm reluctant to add another comment. I know I can count on the original commenter to reply defending their original evaluation, and regardless of whether or not the answer is useful, I feel confident that an argument in the comments about whether or not it should be there is not.

Comment: If you don't feel like sharing your alternate opinion, then feel free not to.  You're not obligated to respond to every comment you see that's incorrect.  It just doesn't mean that the comment is Not Constructive.

Comment: Do you make it a habit of answering off-topic questions?

Comment: @Will I don't think the Q refers specifically to OT questions. Actually, if we were talking only about this then most people would be in favor of such comments. OP is probably referring to other reasons like, for instance, bad grammar or lack of formatting (defects that characterize a bad Q but do not automatically prevent the existence of a good A, although they make it more difficult).

Comment: This seems to be similar to a problem I've seen mentioned once or twice before, where some people will downvote an answer if the _question_ is low-quality, regardless of the answer's quality, simply to get the Roomba to remove the question.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto How do you know what sort of questions are being referred to? The question here says "the usual reason" which is pretty broad to me.

Comment: @mason in fact I wrote that OP does not refer *specifically* to OT and there are many other possible cases as well. Indeed it's broad.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto *OP is probably referring to other reasons like, for instance, bad grammar or lack of formatting* I have ***never*** seen anyone say, or imply, a question shouldn't be answered because of bad grammar or formatting. I haven't ever seen someone even suggest that an answerer should have edited the question prior to answering (since comments were first introduced, and since meta was pro-meat). The only reason why I've ever encountered regularly is because **the question was blatantly off topic**. If my assumption (unclear q, sorry) is incorrect, I invite OP's [edit].

Comment: @Will No, I try to avoid answering off-topic questions. I'm sure I could be better about it, but I do. I really wasn't referring to comments on any of my own answers, though. I apologize if it's unclear. I was trying to make it more about the general case because people often seem to get overly focused on specific examples here. I'm considering how to edit it. I would have asked more carefully if I'd realized it would be this controversial of a topic.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answers-section-on-answering-well-asked-questions-advice-or-site

Comment: OT actually get handled very quickly. Most of answers on questions that are going to be closed later happen on poorly written questions which show formatting or grammar problems, not OT questions. It's really time to stop using a *specific* instance of closed questions to convey a guideline on the more general case. Nobody here has problems on the idea that ridiculously OT questions don't need an answer, but those are far from the only closures you see on SO. There are duplicates, there are posts written in broken English, etc... All of those attract plenty of downvotes and close votes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

No, a comment telling someone they shouldn't have answered a "bad" question is not constructive. If a comment like this is flagged, or I come across one when browsing the site, I'll delete it.

[I keep stating this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions/255861#255861), but going after people who are providing good answers to "bad" questions is counterproductive. It won't do anything to stop bad askers who find this site via Google, are ordered to ask here by their bosses, etc. All it does is irritate and drive away the people who volunteer their time to provide good answers.

Earlier today, [Shog9 articulated how helpful answers can even come out of bad questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348625/answers-that-are-too-detailed/348626#348626), and I'll admit that I've answered plenty of bad questions myself. A bad question can still be a seed for a novel, useful answer, and berating someone for leaving that answer is something I strongly dislike.

Judge answers based on their technical merit. If you don't think the question is appropriate, take action on the question. I can't stop you from voting on the answers however you want, but I almost always will remove comments that admonish people for answering questions.

Comment: Someone posting an answer to an unanswerable question *is a problem with the answer*.  If the problems that a question had didn't inhibit posting great answers then *they wouldn't actually be problems with the question*.  If someone is posting an answer to a question that is completely unclear, or is *way* too broad, or is entirely opinion based, or whatever, then those problems *make the answer a bad answer* (at least in the majority of cases).

Comment: Then perhaps we should remove the section titled "Answer well-asked questions" from [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - Telling people that they'll probably have a better time trying to answer well-asked questions isn't necessarily telling them they are forbidden from answering others. Your odds of being able to answer a well-asked question are higher, but as I point out above, sometimes even poorly asked questions can lead to great answers.

Comment: @BradLarson So then whey do we even close questions in the first place, if there's no problem at all with anyone answering any question, regardless of how bad it is?  The whole reason for closing *existing* is because SO has found that answering certain types of questions causes more harm than good.

Comment: So, it's okay to admonish users in the help section but not the comments? I sometimes point people to `[answer]` indicating they should think about whether it's worth answering a crap question, just like the help section. Now I'm being told not to add comments like that because someone *might* answer with a helpful answer based on guessing or mind-reading or whatever. Just seems like we're saying, "do what you want, answer crap questions because we can't possibly do anything about the flood". It's frustrating to those of me who want to keep the original idea of high quality around.

Comment: Telling people not to answer off-topic questions seems a very good idea to me. Answering, for example, a request for a tutorial, will give us a load of other such questions because people know they will get an answer before the questions gets closed. Answering such "bad" questions is in my opinion actively harming the site.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - What I'm talking about are comments like "This is exactly whats wrong with this site now. Nobody should be answering questions for people too lazy to google." or "I get that you're trying to get rep, but whatever... encourage laziness." being left on good answers by people trying to help out (as two examples flagged and deleted today). The help center is suggesting that your time is better served answering good questions, not that you'll be punished if you happen to answer "bad" questions. It's not that we can't do anything about bad questions, it's that this won't help.

Comment: @BradLarson: It seems to me that those two comments you gave as examples are more borderline rude, or perhaps not constructive for rudeness, than NC for saying the wrong thing. While a comment such as "This question is off-topic because XYZ, and in future it's better for the site if you don't answer such off-topic questions" does not seem to violate Be Nice, and *does* seem to be constructive.

Comment: (For extra cognitive dissonance, I upvoted Shog's answer when I saw it earlier, and I still think it makes sense. I just don't think his defense of occasionally putting extra effort into [especially] downvoted questions can or should be applied to defending answering *close-worthy* questions.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy - You have a point. Almost all of the ones I encounter lie on the harsh-to-rude end of the spectrum. It's rare that I find one expressing this in a polite and informative manner, so maybe I'm overstating things by saying that all of these are not constructive. It's just that if you start with the intent of punishing an answerer to a "bad" question, that usually doesn't lead to polite comments.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson for the answer. I think in the long run negative comments like that do scare away some people who give great answers to otherwise "bad" questions  from the site. Action should be taken against the questions by either editing them or something else and not the answers unless the answers are not proper.

Comment: How do you feel about doing this to people who answer obvious dupes?  I like to leave a message that they should flag/vote to close as a duplicate instead of answering.  I do only do this one then it is a single google search and the first result is the canonical.

Comment: Sorry to see such an answer from staff (counting mods). More evidence that the decline in quality is actually driven by change in company policy (albeit one not matched in the Help Centre) rather than by the masses not following it. Honestly as long as we're being encouraged not to strictly curate, any more, I'm less inclined to bother, and I still strongly believe that if we all stop doing that then we might as well close up shop. Experts Exchange in 3..2..1...!

Comment: @BoundaryImposition - Unless I've missed a memo, I'm not a Stack Exchange employee. This isn't "company policy", it is my personal opinion as a volunteer that other helpful volunteers should be treated with respect. A surefire way to cause a decline in quality is to drive away people contributing quality content, and I'm working to prevent that. I prefer to [go after sources of low-quality content directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295429/streamlining-deletion-of-quality-block-evasion-accounts), rather than attacking the wrong people.

Comment: @BradLarson: "staff (counting mods)" The diamond after your name indicates that you are moderator, or is that no longer so? I always assumed moderators are briefed on and expected to implement company policy. If that is not true, then I (a) apologise, and (b) wonder what track mods are implementing, then.

Comment: @BradLarson People trying to answer unanswerable questions *aren't contributing quality content*.  They're causing *problems*, not being helpful, and informing them of that is appropriate.  If they don't know that they're doing something wrong, then *they can't fix it*.  When you inhibit anyone from ever informing others that they're doing something wrong, and attack and drive away the people that actually care about quality content or the site's site standards, *that's* how you get a decline in quality.

Comment: please ping me when SE team [does something about close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281818/165773) (instead of inventing [useless word bans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281787/165773)) - after that I will change my vote on this post from down to up. As long as active regulars feel powerless in the face of terrible questions flooding the site their negativity will stay and they will find ways to express it no matter how many comments you delete

Comment: @NathanOliver - As long as you keep in mind that what might be an obvious duplicate to you isn't necessarily such to the person answering. They may feel that there are subtle differences, that the answers at the target are insufficient, or they weren't aware of the duplicate to begin with. I'd start by assuming the best about the answerer and be willing to accept that they disagree with your assessment. I've seen plenty of polite discussions go well, in both directions.

Comment: A recent example of @BradLarson **excellent** point is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43711576/1101509). It was written in a very bad way, got 2 downvotes, risked closing. Thanks to a small comment, it got a good answer even before an edit was approved. After the edit was approved it became a decent (even if easy) beginner question, the OP enjoyed learning how to ask properly and agreed to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: @gnat the word ban is not useless, it's just a technical implementation of the policy to prevent rants against people rather than fair criticism on poor content.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I've been thinking just like you few years ago, I loved a policy to keep site professional and free from rants (and still love it mind you). It is only after I discovered that bans like that don't work that I realised that they are useless. Quoting self, "how come that after years of plugging user's mouths and twisting their arms with _summers of love_ and _hunting the snark_ the second top question at MSO is [Why is Stack Overflow so **negative** of late?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758/839601) Makes one wonder if this way works doesn't it"

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto How is that an example of Brad's point at all?  There was a problematic question, the question author got feedback as to the problems with their question, *the question author responded to that feedback by providing relevant information to improve their question*, and *then* the question got an answer.  Nobody provided an answer before the question author responded to the feedback with the additional information, but had they done so, a comment under the answer to indicate that the question was not yet in an answerable state would have been *helpful*, not *harmful*.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto So not only is your example not at all related to this issue, but it's an example that *contradicts* Brad's point.  You've shown an example of someone posting problematic content, someone informing them of why it's problematic, and them fixing it.  Brad is saying that we *shouldn't ever be providing feedback on problematic content* and that he deletes feedback indicating a potential problem with a post, thus inhibiting the author from seeing it and improving their behavior.

Comment: @gnat I didn't mean to say that those bans magically solve the "so negative" problem. I agree with you on that.

Comment: @Servy, yes OP said "I want to reverse a string" before the answer, but the edit (which was actually mine) that turned the "gimme feedback on this code, do you like it?" question into a "this code doesn't work for commas, why?" was approved about 25 minutes *after* the first answer. Yet **the answer to the originally bad question turned out to be good anyway.** With the added plus (and I think it's the most important part) of the OP learning the guidelines for asking good questions. (the bold part is key of Brad's point)

Comment: Also, Brad's post doesn't address the useful comments provided under bad questions, which you correctly appreciate, it's talking about providing good answers to bad questions which should not be discouraged *a priori* but only depending on the single cases.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto You were just taking the information the OP posted in comments and editing it into the question, comments that the OP posted *before the answer was posted*.  Had someone posted a comment on the answer to say that the question wasn't in an answerable state yet, the comment would of course be constructive, but the answerer could merely have replied that the question author had clarified the question in the comments under the question, removing the ambiguity.  Yes, it would have been better for them to edit the question before answering, but the question wasn't unanswerable.

Comment: @Servy "the question wasn't unanswerable". Fair enough. Absolutely agreed. Could it be that I'm viewing Brad's definition of "bad question" in a broader way than you? I don't think it's just about *unanswerable* questions but also other kinds of problematic questions.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto What makes a question bad is that it is either unanswerable, or answers to it would be very likely to be of low quality.  While it's *possible* to provide high quality answers to low quality questions, it's *exceedingly* rare, simply because the *definition* of a low quality question is that it inhibits or prevents quality answers and often encourages low quality answers.

Comment: BTW I will consider if I should delete my previous comment because it seems it's attracting revenge downvotes due to the meta-effect. If someone doesn't agree with my comment it's fine and please tell me like @Servy did. Discussion is useful, but downvoting an inexperienced user because I mentioned their question is not really necessary.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto What would people be downvoting in "revenge" of?  The meta effect is merely describing the fact that a question discussed on meta will attract attention, and some number of the additional viewers of the question may decided to act on the question (say by voting) based on how they feel the question merits said actions, i.e. that a question that the average meta viewer thinks is low quality is likely to attract downvotes *because it's low quality*.  The experience level of a user doesn't make them immune from feedback if their post is in fact low quality.

Comment: @Servy but it isn't in it's current form. It was both slightly off-topic and unclear at the beginning, and that was part of my previous comment, but then got edited to be on-topic and sufficiently clear to get an answer. It doesn't deserve tons of downvotes for the sin of being mentioned on meta. Keeping this toxic environment, users will never learn to fix their posts and correct their errors. They will just run away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143211/discussion-between-andrea-lazzarotto-and-servy).

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto *You* might think that it's a good question, and you're free to use your vote accordingly.  Just because *you* think it's a good question doesn't mean everyone's obligated to agree with you.  You're assuming that other people are downvoting a post purely because it was mentioned on Meta.  That's almost certainly a false assumption.  You have no idea why anyone who may have voted on that post chose to do so.

Comment: I'm astounded this answer received as many upvotes as it did. When we answer questions that are blatantly off-topic, we just encourage them. How many times have you had a user point to some other off-topic question that received an answer as justification for their own off-topic question? I facepalm, then have to explain that just because there exists other questions that break the rules doesn't mean it's okay for them to do so. Let's stop giving them a reason to do so. If someone notifies an answerer why this is a bad practice, that is **absolutely constructive** and shouldn't be removed.

Comment: As for evidence that leaving this constructive comment on answers to blatantly off-topic questions, I submit [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718328/does-microsoft-have-a-html-rich-text-editor-i-do-not-want-to-use-third-party-so) as evidence. Sure, it's just two examples, but I've seen quite a few end up like that. And I consider each of those a success, because now they know better and won't do it again, and may even pass the knowledge along by leaving their own constructive comments for others that do the same thing.

Comment: If you want to stop people giving answers to bad questions then **stop giving them imaginary points for doing so** and **start taking away imaginary points for doing so**...

Comment: I think people agree with each other here more than they realise; from what I've read, Brad is not suggesting an absolute rule. Of course we can find cases that break it, and I think Brad is interested to hear cases that people offer. I think he appreciates improvements on his articulation of which deletion cases are the bad type that he deletes.

Comment: Brad, I think your first sentences sound more absolute than you might have intended. By the way, everyone should notice that this thread is getting noisy now.

Comment: I find useful information in answers to closed questions all the time.

Comment: It kind of depends though, doesn't it? Maybe a question is too broad or deemed too simple but someone can still write a killer answer and it be helpful. In other cases, maybe a question is just really unclear (this happens alot) and people start guessing at answers or writing the same stupid thing that's been answered 80 times without bothering to flag as a duplicate, then not so much.

Comment: @BradLarson based on your comments I think you should change `"bad" question` to something like `"bad", but on-topic question` because that's what you seem to imply. Most challenges you received in the comments are about off-topic questions.

Comment: @Shadow Good point but it's still more nuanced even than that. What about duplicates? It's possible to provide a better answer than the dupe target or take a different approach that is still useful, but it also happens that you just get simple one liners repeated over and over. But then why not just provide another answer to the dupe target? Maybe it doesn't matter, but then what's the point of having duplicate closing in the first place?

Comment: @ThomasPoole you are right about the noise. But as you can see there are some users who think they can impose their views simply by writing their comments in bold. As if bold formatting turned opinions into facts. :D

Comment: Do you think that these comments should be considered intrinsically "unfriendly" under the new Code of Comment? If we flag them as unfriendly/unkind, how would mods be likely to handle them?

Comment: @EJoshuaS - Nothing in the code of conduct has changed how I handle flags on comments like this, so I continue to process them in the way that I describe above (generally, delete). As Nathan Tuggy points out in the above discussion, most of these are plain rude or insulting anyways. However, Jay's [original blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) specifically calls out comments like this ("...the answerer gets scolded for “encouraging ‘low-quality’ questions.”).

Answer (score 28):

In my opinion the constructiveness of such comment heavily relies on the given situation, which is basically fully made up by the question.

---

If the question is one that will be closed later on, then yes, **those comments do have merit**, as users that answer questions that inevitably will get closed later on **deliberately** choose to delay the [deletion of said question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba), which means they directly counter-act the community-driven efforts of keeping this site clean.

On top of that, they're wasting their time, will ultimately gain nothing, and will probably cause even more trouble by complaining about the deletion of their answer as well as the mean, evil and elitist Stack Overflow userbase.

---

However, if the question fits the guidelines for questions but is considered bad due to things like bad indentation, the topic that's being asked about (creation of malware, denial of service, other nasty stuff...), awful grammar or spelling etc., those comments are neither warranted nor constructive, and should be flagged as such.

---

**TL;DR:** If it's clear that the user commenting is aiming at educating the author of the answer in a calm, neutral way about site mechanics (*roomba etc.*), then yes, the comments are constructive. If it's just a rant (*"MUH QUALITIEEE"*), then no, not constructive.

Comment: `for i in xrange(0,10**10): print 'if the question fits the guidelines for questions but is considered bad due to things like bad intendation, awful grammar or spelling etc., those comments are neither warranted nor constructive'`

Comment: I think you missed the words "unless they" before "deliberately choose to delay". (Don't curse too much; I still followed it and maybe nobody else even noticed yet.)

Answer (score 15):

Content-free "your answer is bad and you should feel bad" comments are not helpful, but we have comment flags for them already.

In contrast, it is helpful and even important to warn new users that their answers might be wasting their time or even hurting their reputation.
There are several ways a new user can be punished for answering a bad question, and most are not at all obvious:

### They might be *wasting their time*.

Especially bad questions can be
[deleted by the Community](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba),
taking their answers with them.
Posting an answer prevents this in many cases, but not all.

(The question's author might also never accept or upvote any answers, but I think even a new user could foresee that outcome.)

### They might have to *waste even more time*.

Two related and common forms of bad question are the "chameleon question", which seems clear but changes its meaning later, and the "Heisenquestion", which just trades one ambiguous representation for another.
Answers, even good ones, to the first or most obvious interpretation might become nonsensical later.

The author then has to to either flag the question for moderator attention
(if they are aware of that option),
or update their own post to match.
Otherwise, their helpful and informative answer to Question 1-A will collect
(legitimate)
downvotes for failing to answer Question 42*i*-ReindeerFlotilla.

### They might be *downvoted*.

Discussed in
"[Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963)"
(summary: "yes").
Update:
And contradicted in
"[Is it okay to downvote answers to bad questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459)"
(summary: "no").

New users are generally told that they should start gaining reputation by answering questions, but they can *lose* reputation for decent-enough answers to questions that are duplicates or unclear.

A new user is obviously less likely to spot a duplicate.
He or she is probably less likely to spot a
[help vampire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665),
too.

A new *programmer* is less likely to spot an under-defined question...
If he or she only knows one possible interpretation, then *obviously* the question is fully-specified and suitable for answering.

---

I think these are all things a new user should know, but is unlikely to learn on their own.
A comment is a more gentle teacher
(and maybe even more effective)
than a downvote or a deletion.

Comment: eh, dunno. they seem to react to downvotes far more often than constructive comments. Many of these users simply don't care that they're not helping the site; They're still getting the feel good feeling of helping the OP, so their goal is met.

Comment: @KevinB:  The question was "Are those comments constructive, or just noise?", and I think the ones that (attempt to) instruct can be helpful.  A comment might not get through to any particular user, but the attempt alone shouldn't qualify the comment as noise.

Comment: The guideline about downvoting answers to bad questions has changed: See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459 (Now the answer is NO)

Comment: @user000001:  Is there some way of knowing which is the correct answer (assuming there is such a thing)?  I've had the "yes" answer bookmarked for some time, and never noticed any contradiction until your reply just now.  I see that the "no" Q&A is newer and has more votes, but it also has highly upvoted dissenting answers.  Based on this new information, I can update my belief from "settled: downvote" to "undecided", but I think it would take a closing of the original question or a message from Stack Exchange, Inc. to slide all the way to "settled: do not downvote".  Does such evidence exist?

Comment: @user000001 that isn't a guideline. just a shared opinion.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, but only in limited circumstances like

1. The user answers by copying and linking to another answer on a duplicate question. Sometimes users don't know that they should flag the question as a duplicate.
2. The question is too broad and/or effortless. Questions like "How I make website?" should not be answered. Giving the questioner a checklist isn't helpful. Flag them for closure.
3. Guessing at answers. Sometimes the question doesn't give you enough to formulate an answer. So some eager users make a guess, which means you [wind up with answers that look like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJwTQoflevI). Again, these should be flagged for closure or a comment should be left asking for more clarification.

Comment: I also letting them know about the habit of DVing answers of low-quality questions (Yes, it happens here on SO). I don't suggest that the should not answer, but just letting them know that this things happens. Especially if it's a simple 2-3 lines answer

Comment: I've recently seen a 300k+ user answering a typo question that he was the first to VTC as typo... I couldn't resist commenting about this.

Answer (score 7):

Since you don't provide examples, I don't know if this is your case, but I think when there is a question that is clearly a homework question, and an answer that provides an answer ready to turn in without the asker having to understand or learn anything, a comment that such answers are not the best way to answer such questions is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

That depends on how good the answer is.

Stack Overflow is trying to be a repository of high-quality Q&A, not low-quality answers to low-quality questions or even mediocre answers to low-quality questions. If someone's answering a bad question, they should at least provide a very good answer to make the Q&A worth keeping around. A low-quality or mediocre answer doesn't really justify keeping a bad question around. For example, if someone provides a low-effort answer to a typo and the OP accepts it, this clearly has little to no value to the site - all they've done is create more work for other people by forcing us to delete it manually.

One other case where this kind of comment *is* constructive is cases where the question is unclear, overly broad, or incomplete to the point that we don't know if the answer(s) are addressing the OP's problem at all (or answers are just guessing/speculating as to what the problem is). In cases like this, it's really not possible to write a good answer, so the answer probably deserves to be downvoted on its own merit anyway. In cases like this, it's constructive to suggest that they wait for the OP to improve the question before answering so that they can write an adequate answer.

Another possible case is [obvious XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but again, this kind of answer probably deserves to be downvoted on its own merit anyway for not addressing the OP's actual problem.

One final example case is homework dumps. Since [students **must** practice in order to learn to program](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems), it's not helpful to them or to the site for someone to just spoon-feed them the code. In that case, it's absolutely constructive to comment telling the answerer not to do the OP's homework for them.

For a good answer that addresses the OP's problem, though, this kind of comment is not constructive.

Comment: This makes sense in the context of duplicate questions.  If the answer regurgitates information from the dupe, it's not adding anything new and really shouldn't have been posted in the first place.

Comment: @Makoto And if it *is* a novel, useful, additional solution to the problem, beyond what's already on the canonical *we want it posted to the canonical*, not the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Locally? No. It's obviously going to help neither the asker of that question, nor the answerer (at least not directly).

But one thing many people seem unwilling to do around here is to consider the bigger picture. I think that this "help at all costs" mentality is exactly why our repository is so incredibly balanced towards the terrible-quality side of things.

If we can turn one answerer away from the habit of encouraging more terrible questions by answering them, then so much the better. Of course, it should be done politely. Under these circumstances, if you are hurt or offended by such a comment, then you're going to need to take a step back and interpret it in the way it was meant: an attempt to make a *constructive* comment regarding the wider implications of your personal answering policy. It's up to all of us to do our part, even if sometimes it seems easier "not to bother" because "they just keep on coming anyway". That sort of mentality will lead us ever-closer to Experts Exchange status, precisely the opposite of what this place is supposed to be.

Flagging these comments as non-constructive absolutely helps nobody, and *that* is non-constructive.

Comment: Rather than straight out telling someone, choose to warn them I'd say. But the problem with the bigger picture is that it is just so darned big on Stack Overflow, very few people that frequent it really judge well the consequences of actions and a lack of action. I wonder if leaving such comments around for all eyes to see and copy will have negative effects of its own for example.

Answer (score -6):

> Are those comments constructive, or just noise?

This is a false dichotomy, in my opinion.

Such a comment might not be constructive (it's at least debatable) - but at the same time still a reasonable comment to make (and certainly not noise). Who says everything needs to be constructive?

... however, it should be polite and explicit about the reason.

Comment: Comments are ripe for removal.  An unconstructive comment usually doesn't last very long.

Comment: @Makoto: Too bad. Sometimes it's important to be unconstructive.

Comment: We require that questions and answers be useful, why wouldn't we require the same of comments?

Comment: @BSMP: Not only constructive comments are useful. A "destructive" comment can also have some use.

Comment: I think we're working with two different definitions of the word "constructive".

Comment: @BSMP: "Constructive, adj: 1. helping to improve; promoting further development or advancement (opposed to destructive)". Suggesting an answer be removed is not helping to improve it, nor to develop it, nor to advance it.