# How to report abuse when the answer has been deleted

Tags: support, abuse

This morning I came to a question that I thought I could answer, but before I got the chance someone had answered it.  While reading through this answer some comments appeared, they went as follows:

User to Answerer

> "Are you sure we should be answering questions like this?"

Answerer to User

> "Look, we've been over this.  Leave me alone!"

Now I answered the question and went back to work, but this exchange started to bother me and I started to think this might be a case of ongoing abuse.  I got back on and went to flag the comment for moderation but the answer post was deleted so the comments are no longer available.  As a result, I can no longer report this possible abuse.

I can direct a moderator to the question and the user that is possibly being abusive, but I cannot find a form for reporting abuse.

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Just because you *can* answer does not mean you *should*. This does not sound like abuse to me. It sounds like someone was pointing this out.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to step in here but if you feel strongly about it just mod flag on your answer or the question, let them know what you saw and tell them your suspicions.

Comment: Just because someone doesn't want to hear constructive and valid criticisms of their answer and doesn't *care* that they're doing something wrong doesn't make the person providing constructive criticism abusive.  You have that reversed.  It's the person that's knowingly doing things that they shouldn't, and ignoring the constructive advice as to what they're doing wrong and yelling at that person for *appropriately trying to make the site a better place*, that's being abusive.

Comment: @Paulie_D If the commentor had felt it wasn't a good question then they should have downvoted it rather than commenting on an answer and if the answer was the problem then they could have actually offered criticism or simply downvoted.  The response from the answerer made me think this keeps happening, so either a moderator needs to step in and talk to this user about his low quality answers or a moderator needs to step in and talk to the other user about his abusive behavior.

Comment: @Servy I don't consider this to be a constructive criticism, but that's why I would turn to moderators for help.  They would be able to look at the deleted answer and users' histories and make an informed decision.  Note I said in my question "this might be a case of ongoing abuse".

Comment: @Eric Answering low quality questions leads to *more* low quality questions. We all have a reponsibility to maintain the *quality* of the questions. Adding comments to this effect is not *abuse* by my definition.

Comment: @Eric Even if you disagree with the user's criticism, it's still *constructive*.  If you feel that the answer is a quality answer and that post it was useful and appropriate, feel free to indicate that you feel that the criticism was incorrect. That doesn't make it *abusive*.  As to the validity of the *constructive* criticism, SO is built on the premise that quality questions lead to quality answers, and low quality questions lead to low quality answers.  If low quality questions didn't affect their ability to be answered (well) then *they wouldn't be low quality questions*.

Comment: @Paulie_D We also have a responsibility to create a safe environment for all users.  I understand that low quality questions/answers are an issue, that wasn't the focus of this question, how to handle potential abuse was.  Reading through the "Be Nice" section of the help center I considered this exchange as "rude and belittling" and/or "bullying".

Comment: From the comments you have quoted *none* of them are "rude and belittling" and/or "bullying". I dispute your interpretation. If this q/A had not been deleted I suspect your flag would have been declined.

Comment: @Servy "Are you sure we should be answering questions like this?"  is a criticism but I wouldn't consider it constructive.  A simple downvote would have been a better way to handle it.  The question was fine, it was clear what was being asked and had a code example to follow.  The answer wasn't right, but again, a downvote would have done the job.

Comment: As Brad said.. *"In this case, the comment wasn't particularly abusive and didn't really warrant any additional action. "*

Comment: @Eric It is neither of those things.  *Correctly* and *politely* informing a user that they've done something wrong is not rude, belittling, or bullying.  *You* are the one acting inappropriate here by insulting someone for providing constructive criticism, and bullying someone for *appropriately* trying to make the site better, all because you have a problem with the idea of having quality standards.

Comment: @Eric How is the criticism not constructive?  It's informing the answerer of what they've done wrong, so they can attempt to rectify the problem and perhaps avoid it in the future. Yes, a downvote would be appropriate, and I agree that many answerers (like apparently this one, and you) are unable to accept constructive criticism and simply get defensive and attack the person providing the helpful feedback, but the problem is not the way the feedback was delivered, but that the recipient chose to attack the person giving it.

Comment: @servy I didn't insult anyone.  I am also trying to help maintain a level of quality by bringing this question to meta.  I received a good answer and some comments.  And yes Paulie_D I do agree that this comment isn't necessarily abusive, the answerer reaction leads me to believe this is an ongoing issue.  I appreciate everyone's help on this.

Comment: @Servy I see your point.

Comment: @Eric Yes, you did insult someone.  You accused them of being abusive, bullying someone, belittling someone, and of being rude, when they in fact provided helpful and polite feedback on a post, and did none of those things.  I don't consider trying to inhibit the ability of anyone to tell anyone, politely, that there is a problem with the quality of their contributions, and to therefore encourage the posting of low quality content, to be someone that is "maintaining a level of quality" on the site.

Comment: @Servy he didn't provide helpful feedback, there are many other people who thought answering that question would be a good idea. As quite often with those comments, Rajesh is standing far alone

Comment: @baao paraphrased "others posted answers as well so it must be a good question" is a non sequitur. The JavaScript and jQuery are a cesspool of low-effort questions and low-quality answers. Just the fact that 5 other users (including a 100K+ rep one...) could answer a question doesn't mean it was a good question.

Comment: Did you read the question @CodeCaster ?

Comment: @Servy: "*I don't consider trying to inhibit the ability of anyone to tell anyone, politely*" It stops being "polite" if it becomes a repeated thing. To post such a comment on multiple answers from a person is de-facto abuse, no matter how "polite" you are to them. And considering the response from the answerer, this clearly is a repeated thing, not a one-off comment.

Comment: @NicolBolas it was only the second time within 4 months for me, but the particular user regularly comments that kind of comments on many people's answers. Keeping in mind that he has 50% answers without a single upvote, I just think he should concentrate on being helpful himself before trying to educate others.

Comment: After stepping away from this question and coming back, I'd like to provide a little clarification.  I agree that the comment alone wasn't abusive, what I was concerned with was the way the answerer reacted.  As you pointed out, some people can react negatively to criticism, I also agree with this, but when the commentor addressed the answerer rather than the OP, a flag went up in my mind.  This looked like a control issue coupled with the implication that this has been an ongoing issue.  I probably should not have called it abuse, but an indication of an abusive relationship.

Comment: @NicolBolas If someone makes the same mistake multiple times, it makes sense to point it out each of those times.  Repeatedly pointing it out *for a single instance* would be impolite, but that's not what's happening.  That someone is actively ignoring all constructive feedback given to them doesn't mean that providing constructive feedback on new content is abusive.

Comment: I feel like many of the comments in this thread are off-topic.  I think this was a good question, but that my example took away from this.  It would have been appreciated if someone had pointed this out from the beginning and I could have edited my answer.  I don't want to do this at this point because it would render this comment thread null and void.

Comment: @Servy: "*That someone is actively ignoring all constructive feedback given to them doesn't mean that providing constructive feedback on new content is abusive.*" Yes, it does. Constantly badgering someone to stop doing something, even if you're polite about it, is still abusive. They've clearly made their decision, and so long as they're not violating any site rules, you have no right to badger them to stop.

Comment: @NicolBolas They don't have a right to prohibit people from providing feedback on problems with posts, just because they want to be able to provide bad posts.  If someone has made the decision that they want to continue to engage in a problematic behavior, one consequence of that is that they may continue to be informed that they're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Servy: Just don't be surprised if such people are sanctioned for a pattern of abusive behavior.

Comment: @NicolBolas I mean I'm not *entirely* surprised that there are lots of people that care more about a user's ability to post low quality content without being informed that they're posting low quality content, than it does about ensuring that people actually post quality content.  The people that actually value quality contributions and enforcing quality standards has always been decreasing, and the people that try to actually enforce the site's rules have been continually inhibited from doing so, so I'd be more disappointed than surprised.

Comment: @Servy: Do you not see the hypocrisy of breaking the rules to defend them? It's not about caring "more about a user's ability to post low quality content"; it's about us having rules about people repeatedly annoying others. Your good intentions do not put you above the rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas It's not hypocrisy because *politely informing a user that they're doing something wrong isn't breaking the rules*, so it's not breaking the rules to enforce the rules.  You don't just suddenly become immune from the consequences of breaking the rules just because you've broken them lots of times.  If a user is annoyed when they're informed that they're doing something wrong they should *stop doing that wrong thing* rather than complaining about a user pointing out when they do that wrong thing.

Comment: @Servy: Harassment is still harassment, even if it is stated "politely". If someone has repeatedly broken the rules, the correct answer is to escalate matters, not to keep harassing them about it.

Comment: @NicolBolas But this isn't harassment.  If the comments weren't actually providing constructive feedback, and were just designed to annoy the person, *then* it would be harassment, but instead it's pointing out a problem that should be addressed.

Comment: @baao yes, I read the question. It goes something _"How can I make a method count from 1 to 5 the first time I call it, and from 6 to 10 the second time, and so on?"_. I don't think that's a really useful question, especially not for others besides the OP. I, IMHO, don't really think that's the kind of question a 30K rep, let alone 100K rep user should answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In extreme cases of abuse involving a deleted post, you can flag the question or even one of your unrelated posts and provide a link in the custom flag along with an explanation of what went on. If you can't access the deleted answer, link to the question and explain that it's in a deleted answer there. We can see all deleted answers, and should be able to figure out the context.

In this case, the comment wasn't particularly abusive and didn't really warrant any additional action. It had already been flagged, in fact, and that flag was marked as helpful once the parent post was deleted.

Comment: can you help me @Brad Larson someone deleted their question right after I answered it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61846566/run-scripts-and-css-of-html-file-fetched-with-chrome-runtime-geturl?noredirect=1#comment109415460_61846566

Answer (score 6):

As I'm the person whose comment you've quoted, here are my two cents. The question you are talking about [How to loop through a object to give me 5 items at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351797/how-to-loop-through-a-object-to-give-me-5-items-at-a-time/45351851#45351851) was a well formed question and has gained 5 answers apart from mine (which I've deleted because I answered it wrong).

The user who commented

> I'm just wondering should we answer such questions?

Is commenting tons of answers similar like above if he personally thinks that a question is too easy, or whatever. I had a discussion with him about his behaviour earlier, and after hearing and evaluating his opinions, I must say that I don't agree to them. That's why I commented

> I've already spent enough time discussing with you. @Rajesh . Don't answer it if you don't want to, but leave me alone!

If I made you feel uncomfortable I sincerely apologize.

SIDENOTE

I strongly disagree that the user's comment was constructive critic in any way!!!

Comment: Says _I'm just wondering should we answer such questions?_ and then answers the question in the comments anyway. I wouldn't say it was an abusive comment, but a hypocritical one for sure.

Comment: Yah.. :D He's something special... @George

Comment: I may not have made this clear in my answer, but while I didn't think Rajesh's comment was particularly abusive or worth revisiting after the post had been deleted, it most likely would have been deleted if flagged as "no longer needed". That whole conversation didn't really add anything to the answer, and we [tend to remove comments telling people not to answer things when flagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348634/19679) and clean up the comment fights they often start.

Comment: I don't think it was rude, too @BradLarson . I agree that it was solely not needed...