# Answerer is answering debugging questions that lack code. Should I care?

Tags: discussion

## This question is not duplicate! The other question is about questioners. This question is about answerers!

What to do about an answerer that answers questions for which the user has not followed the rule that the code required to reproduce a bug must be in the question itself.

Instead this user always asks the questioner to make a JSFiddle and then answers the question by posting a new JSFiddle with explanation but no or little code.

I think the answerer is being excellent by helping questioners but they're effectively using stack overflow as an answer forum instead of a repository of answers since the answers (and questions) just link to offsite code

I've commented on many of their answers and comments. When they ask for a fiddle I point out they should be asking for an MCVE in the question, not just a link to a JSFiddle. But it's been months now and they clearly have no intention of changing.

Should I care? Should I follow their example? Should I report them to a mod?

Note: my general response has been to edit the question and copy the code into it via a snippet, then leave a comment that they should have used a snippet in the first place but I'm getting really tired of the manual labor and the fact that the answerer is encouraging more of the same making more work for me.

Just to reiterate

1. Question asks for debugging help without MCVE
2. Answerer ask for jsfiddle instead of MCVE
3. Answerer answers with jsfiddle link and explanation

Should I care about the answerer continuing to not ask to make the question on topic. In fact they are arguably going against the site's guidelines. The site itself tries to prevent fiddle links without code. The user pastes in some code but often it is not MVCE. It's not enough to repo, it's not complete.

This is not a dupe of: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572)
That question is about questioners, this question is about the answerer

It is also not a dupe of: [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)
That question is about asking people not to answer. This question is about people asking for off topic edits.

Comment: If the question is off-topic, it's simple; vote to close.  Vote to delete once able.  Once enough members do so, both the question and any answers (and whatever rep gains there were) disappear.

Comment: in an ideal world... no, you shouldn't care, because there'd be enough other people casting close votes on posts that should be closed such that it doesn't matter that someone decided to take a wild guess.

Comment: @fbueckert, okay, so I should stop making the questions on topic by fix them and just vote to close. Got it.

Comment: If you can edit it to make it on-topic, it is a valid solution.  It is not required, but can be done if you want to.  Usually, though, if a question doesn't have code, that's not something you can actually do.  Linking it in the comments is no good, and askers need to sometimes be reminded to put it in the question itself.  If it's not there, there's no guarantee the fiddle will last long enough to help future readers.

Comment: Of all the misery caused by crappy questions, having two people that can actually contribute useful content sniping at each other like that has to be the worst.  That blog post does indeed say *You can still use sites like JSFiddle if you prefer them*, so he's got you there.  You can start a meta question about it, decent odds you'll get mileage out of it.

Comment: ... there's nothing wrong with posting a fiddle in comments while trying to clarify the problem the user is having... stack snippets is not a replacement of that.

Comment: Note that JSFiddle does not attach any license to their fiddles, so all rights are reserved and copying it to Stack Overflow would be a license violation.

Comment: If there was code in the question that was enough to repo the issue I wouldn't be complaining. usually though the questioner doesn't know what code is causing the issue. If they post any code it's often not enough to repo the issue. Therefore the question is off topic. The anserwer posts a comment saying "please post a jsfiddle" so the question is still off topic. The answner then answers with a jsfiddle. I was trying to make them on topic so the questioner gets their answer and so future visitors will see a useful question but I see I was wrong. I'll just vote to close and move on.

Comment: The fact the some answerer is basically abusing SO I guess is immaterial though that was the point of the question. A user is not asking to make questions on topic. They are taking off topic questions and then asking for offsite examples and answering with offsite examples.

Comment: You could also downvote the answer, since it is (in my mind at least) not useful, since the code is on a site I often find blocked by corporate firewalls.

Comment: Do these questions ever eventually get deleted or are they hanging around because they've been answered?

Comment: While its obviously better that code exists in the Answer. JSFiddle is really neato in terms of being able to mess with the code and probe how it works. That said the resource is out of SOs orbit, and a good answer can be rendered a useless answer if the non SO page goes away. Can you just edit the code into the answer yourself?

Comment: @Shayne re: editing it in: see my comment above

Comment: Ah that is an unfortunate complication

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: Also related: [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

Comment: @EJoshuaS, it's not a dupe of either of those. The first link is about questioners, this question is about answerers. The second is about discouraging answerers. This question has nothing to do with discouraging answerers. It has to do with an answerer asking for off topic edits.

Comment: JSFiddle says: *"JSFiddle is for: [...] Presenting code answers on Stack Overflow"*. Should we be concerned?

Comment: @PasserBy If they were implying a direct relationship with Stack Overflow it would be a reason for concern, but I don't think this does. Nor does it say that links to their site are sufficient for answers. It'd be worth asking if it their [Answers on Stack Overflow](https://docs.jsfiddle.net/use-cases/answers-on-stack-overflow) documentation could include the rule requiring the code also be here but it's not a huge problem if they don't. This isn't like a company claiming SO can be used for customer support questions.

Comment: 4 words: **What is your goal?** To make yourself feel better? Or to help the guy? Or to help other people? And how would downvoting/closing/deleting/etc. help achieve your goal?

Comment: @mehrdad, my goal is to see stack overflow used as the site directs it to be used. A repository of questions and answers. The answerer I'm bringing up is not doing that. Instead they are using S.O. as an answer forum for their project of choice. The question being offtopic and the answer also being offtopic means they are not contributing to S.O., they're just abusing it as a tech support place for their library.

Answer (score 15):

You are correct that questions that require code (such as questions asking for debugging help/'why isn't my code working') require it *in the question body* in the form of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (for questions about 'why is my code not working').

If you see questions lacking required code in the question body, vote to close using the appropriate close reason. Otherwise, if you can edit the question yourself (without violating a license like copying substantial code from a JSFiddle link into the question body) to bring it into compliance with site requirements, you are encouraged to do so.

It's a tricky situation to handle answers on these questions -- on the one hand, there's guidance that our votes are ours to do with as we please... on the other hand, the system indicates downvotes are for content that is wrong or not useful. If you truly think the answer is not useful, either in a microscopic or macroscopic sense, then of course feel free to downvote. I would not recommend flagging the user -- moderators on Stack Overflow do not usually engage in correcting the behavior of users this way.

Comment: I didn't say anything about requiring a snipping. I said the question doesn't have enough code to repo and the answerer only asks for a fiddle, they don't ask for the code to be put in the question.

Comment: @gman In the question, you said "When they ask for a fiddle I point out they should be asking for snippet". That indicates you think a Snippet is required (or at least, should be given instead of a JSFiddle link). If you mean something else, please edit the question to clarify what you mean.

Comment: The answerer is asking for a working example. If they want a working example (ie, an mCve where C = complete then it needs to be in the question, not in fiddle. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @gman Thanks, that is a difference; I've edited your question to include that clarification and will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: I still think I'm failing to make the point of my question. To put it another way, what should I do if anything to push the answerer to stop encouraging more off topic edits and questions. Downvoting is a very weak signal to the answerer. Especially if it doesn't lead to an early close.

Comment: @gman Sorry, was just editing my answer a second time after your last question addendum. See if that last paragraph of mine helps address your concern.

Comment: I still failed to make my point. As it is the **answerer** is bascially giving the finger to S.O's guidelines. They are both asking the questioner to keep the question off topic and then answering the off topic question. If S.O. wants people to follow the guidelenss then there needs to be some way to interveen when answerers are basically using the site as a support forum instead of actually following the rules. As it is there is nothing to do to. The answerer will continue to flaunt the rules with immpunitiy and there is zero way to give them a signal to stop.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Question asks for debugging help without MCVE

Not uncommon.  There's of course nothing you, personally, can do about this.

> 2. Answerer ask for jsfiddle instead of MCVE

The user in question no doubt does so because it is practical for them, or because it serves some other personal agenda, such as jsFiddle advocacy.  Nothing you can say or do is likely to change that.  That they continue such behavior in spite of your repeated attempts to persuade them to do otherwise suggests that they are not motivated by the Stack philosophy about what we're doing here, so they are likely to continue doing it as long as they find it practical and and valuable to them.

Instead of attempting to instruct the answerer on the proper approach -- which I agree is to ask for the OP to put all needed code into the question itself -- you should ask the OP directly to do the right thing.  You may even attempt to override the rogue answerer's request with something like:

> *Although we indeed do need code demonstrating the problem in order to adequately address your question, please edit such code into the question itself, where it will benefit others experiencing similar problems, as described in our instructions for asking questions [link to how-to-ask].*

If the OP does not comply, whether they provide a fiddle or not, close-voting the question is an appropriate response.  You may CV even before the OP has the opportunity to comply -- remember that you can always retract your CV later if appropriate.  If the OP does provide a fiddle, then editing (parts of) it into the question *may* be a reasonable alternative, depending on whether you remain within your rights in doing so.

It is even possible that over time, this approach will persuade the other user to change their behavior, especially if others frequenting the tag pick up the same practice.

> 3. Answerer answers with jsfiddle link and explanation

Depending on the details, it might be reasonable to flag such an answer for deletion as link-only, but if there is sufficient explanation in it then that probably will not fly.

You could also consider editing code into the answer, again ensuring that you remain within your rights.  Of course, the poster can roll back such edits, but if you are persistent (across multiple such answers -- no edit war, please) then the other user may tire of that game.

I would also consider this sufficient reason to downvote the answer, which might sting, and which might also contribute to more of these particular Q/A pairs being roomba'd.

Comment: Did you mean flag answer for deletion? There's no CV for answers. Then we run into the problem that deletion is really hard.

Comment: Indeed I did, @PasserBy.  Edited.

Comment: Copying a JSFiddle into a post and turning it into a runnable Stack snippet is categorically the correct thing to do. Only extremely extenuating circumstances could possibly change that. Saying is "may be a reasonable alternative" is a gross understatement of how appropriate it is. Barring some very out of the ordinary reason, it is the policy on the matter. Furthermore, doing it on the *answer* will at worst trigger an edit war, which gives the editor a reason to flag and moderators a reason to intervene since the edit complies with policy and undoing it does not.

Comment: @jpmc26 "categorically the correct thing to do"... well, only the copyright owner has the right to change the license on their code. JSFiddle does not enforce a license (from their "Fiddler meta": "All code belongs to the poster and no license is enforced."). By copying the code here, you are applying a CC-by-SA 3.0 license to it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey If the author doesn't want it licensed, they can flag for it to be scrubbed from the DB and we can close/delete the question. Hopefully before they get an answer.

Comment: @jpmc26 Sounds a bit iffy, legally speaking, but IANAL :).

Comment: @jpmc26, it is not acceptable to violate someone else's copyright, period.  The relicensing isn't even the primary issue here -- it's copying content from JSFiddle in the first place.  But even if it were just the relicensing, it is a reflection of the fact that the author's rights have been violated that they even *can* successfully petition for redress.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Then JS Fiddle links should be blacklisted. SO's requirement is post your code in the question. Users are *not* allowed to circumvent that. Period. You want help from this community? You do it on this community's terms or you go away. I'm sick of people hiding behind inane technicalities, and I'm sick of people who won't go along with those standards trying to undermine our efforts to create a site with decent questions.

Comment: @jpmc26, I fully agree that the code belongs in the answer. I'd be fine with blacklisting JSFiddle links in questions and answers, though I think it unlikely to actually happen.  Whether it does or not, however, insisting that people's rights be respected and that community members behave lawfully with respect to their on-site activities is *not* "hiding behind inane technicalities."

Answer (score 2):

The policy of "moderate the content, not the user" applies here. Instead of trying to fix these trash questions, use the tools available to you to deal with trash questions: downvote, vote to close, vote to delete, **move on to the next one**.

The end result is that these trash questions will go bye-bye and accordingly, so will the answers from our JSFiddler. If s/he is answering these questions just to assist help vampires, that won't change anything for them or the vampires; if not, s/he will get discouraged by their wasted effort and either shape up to SO's standards, or bugger off to a forum somewhere.

I know a lot of people are going to say "wow, why would you want to chase away such a valuable contributor?" But this answerer **is not a valuable contributor by Stack Overflow's standards**: s/he is causing problems by wasting your time and encouraging poor-quality questions.

Rules exist for a reason, SO's rules exist for a reason, **and if you aren't willing to follow the rules after being warned about them multiple times, then you aren't welcome here, regardless of how "helpful" you think you're being**.

Comment: "If s/he is answering these questions just to assist help vampires, that won't change anything for them or the vampires; if not, s/he will get discouraged by their wasted effort and either shape up to SO's standards, or bugger off to a forum somewhere." Unlikely. Most trash questions remain unclosed and undeleted; the questions are frequently upvoted enough to outweight the lost reputation from downvoters. This means both the asker and the answerer reap the reward of reputation. It's a positive feedback loop, leading to an ever growing problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are so interested in the health of such questions, then edit the code into the body of the question, or request that either the asker or answerer do.

In all honesty, it behooves anyone who answers using code provided in comments from the OP (only when it is from the asker), to then edit that content into the question.

You get fancy badges from it even.

- Explainer (Bronze): Edit and answer 1 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
- Refiner (Silver): Edit and answer 50 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)
- Illuminator (Gold): Edit and answer 500 question (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

All this other conjecture of how to pitchfork someone serves no purpose, and those comments will just be removed from a flag which wastes moderator time.

Comment: The answerer doesn't care about badges. As I said, they are just using S.O. as their support forum and ignoring the rules.

Comment: @gman - From the 20 answers of their I just looked at, it doesn't really seem like they are "just using SO as their support forum". I also don't see any sort of actual materialization of the claims you made in their posts with regards to only asking for fiddles, only using fiddles, and ignoring the rules. They use a fiddle in their answer, along with including the code from it, and don't seem to exhibit the behavior of solely requesting a fiddle and nothing else from the OP. In fact, a majority of the time the OP's code is already present.

Comment: @gman - What I did see was an instance of disagreement between you two in comments, at which point you seem to have attempted to anonymize the situation here. As noted, no need for pitchforks, hyperbole, etc. You make some broad claims here with regards to a specific user, and I just don't see any evidence of them exhibiting that behavior.

Comment: Editing the code in would be a license violation given that JSFiddle does not attach a license to user contributions. That means all rights are reserved. Please do not encourage users to edit code into posts from JSFiddle unless it is their own code.

Comment: @TinyGiant - There is really nothing accurate about that statement. If you have given this advice elsewhere, you need to correct it at your earliest convenience. If you are going to give legal advice, perhaps seek actual legal counsel first. For the avoidance of doubt: "**NO LICENSE IS ENFORCED**" is directly stated by JSFiddle. If the OP shares a fiddle of their situation, then users should be encouraged to edit that into the question if it is not already.

Comment: No license is enforced means all rights reserved, not you can do whatever you like. Licenses allow you to do things that you would otherwise not be allowed to do. If there is no license then you're not allowed to release it under a license unless you are the owner of the code.

Comment: JSFiddle will not take part in any sort of indication of ownership. Unless that code is clearly represented elsewhere, there is no way to cite copyright. If it is represented elsewhere, then that is the copyright which would be enforced, which would be the only possible constitution to consider. However, when looking at a fiddle, it should also be immediately obvious if the situation being presented is part of an actual license. In general, as well, code which is used at JSFiddle will include license in it if cited, which must also be copied if the code is included.

Comment: In no way does using content from JSFiddle present a problem so long as the code originated there.

Comment: @TravisJ That argument is not a legal argument. JSFiddle doesn't own the code, the author of the code does. The author of the code did not release the code under a license and as such all rights are reserved. Plain and simple, no if's and's or but's about it. There is no argument to the contrary. The code is not licensed and cannot therefore be released under a license at all whatsoever unless done so by the author of the code. Telling people that they can do that is disingenuous, misleading, and at worst it can be actively harmful, possibly leaving the editor in legal trouble.

Comment: @TinyGiant - Telling people that their code is legally protected by anonymously publishing it with JSFiddle is terrible advice. As is the rest of your commentary. Show me one case where what you describe was part of a court decision. You can't, because it is not a legally defensible position and literally no lawyer worth their salt would even go there. That you are trying to cite a legal precedence with regards to editing in a minor snippet to a question just shows the terrible level of pedantism being peddled by those who claim they are only helping others by "curating". It is disgusting.

Comment: I'm detailing the law. You're saying the law doesn't matter because people can do whatever they want. the fact is that the law is the law regardless of how many people flout it. Again you're not making a legal argument here. You position is patently false and it has no defense. I'm sorry that you feel the need to give people horrible legal advice from the standpoint that laws don't matter, but frankly _that_ is disgusting.

Comment: You should read up on [the Berne convention](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention) which says that all works are protected from the moment they are created. Licenses allow you to do things you would otherwise not be allowed to do. They do not prevent you from being able to do things you would otherwise be able to do without a license.

Comment: I am aware, but it doesn't really apply in the situation discussed. If the OP rep's that the code is theirs, and attempts to include that code by giving a link because they do not understand how to properly use Stack Overflow, then including it is a good faith effort. There are no legal ramifications, and if the OP is so inclined and feels that the inclusion is incorrect they may request a takedown of material, which still has no ramification on an individual user.

Comment: It's still a blatant violation of copyright law, but that's alright because laws are for other people, right? No the law is the law. You've still yet to make a legal argument here.

Comment: I understand that it may be a little too complicated for you to grasp the argument being presented, but that's alright. The law is the law, and it clearly allows for this situation.