# Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?

Tags: discussion, answers

Closely related: [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

From [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Not all questions can or should be answered here. Save yourself some frustration and avoid trying to answer questions which...
>   ...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem.
>   ...solicit opinions rather than facts.
>   ...have already been asked and answered many times before.
>   ...require too much guidance for you to answer in full, or request answers to multiple questions. 
>   ...are not about programming as defined in the help center.

Is this intended to be an actual site policy (i.e. don't answer bad questions), or is it just a suggestion (i.e. you're wasting your time because it may be deleted anyway)?

This seems to be *worded like* a suggestion ("save yourself some frustration"), but everything else described in the document is actual site policy and is generally grounds for the answer to be deleted in the VLQ queue. For example:

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

In this case, it's actual site policy (and the community consensus) that link-only answers are bad answers. *Not* following this will likely get the answer deleted in the VLQ queue.

So, which is this - policy or advice? If it's policy, how should we handle answers?

Comment: Answering bad questions is possible, it often leads to the answer being downvoted and sometimes deleted (usually when the question gets deleted) so it's at your own risk.

Comment: And of course, even if this is just a suggestion, why are users prohibited from informing other users of this site suggestion?

Comment: If it is policy, it isn't enforcable. A question being a "bad" question is often subjective (hence why closing a question usually requires more than one vote.)

Comment: @KevinB That's true, but there are some questions that are so egregiously bad that anyone in their right mind would know it shouldn't be asked here (e.g. when someone literally copies and pastes their homework assignment into the question and expects someone else to do it for them).

Comment: but... even that may not always be off topic/closable. the problem is it isn't always easy for everyone to identify that a question is clearly off topic. it's clearly off topic to the trained eye, but not all answeres are seasoned answerers.

Comment: When the assignment is a question that is answerable. "How do you do <insert well defined task>?"

Comment: @KevinB I'm not sure I follow - when would a zero-effort homework dump ever *not* be closable?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Any time that it is not too broad, unclear, primarily opinion based, a duplicate, or off-topic for any other prescribed reason. A question being a homework question does not in and of itself make the question off-topic. Those questions just irk people because they show a lack of effort, which is a perfectly acceptable reason to _downvote_ a question, but is not a reason to close a question.

Comment: There is no flag for answers like this, so it's not really policy.  However, people who answer off topic questions chance having their work deleted or downvoted by people who don't like folks encouraging the practice.  Consequently, "frustration" can be saved by not answering them.

Comment: Overall, we are desperately lacking formal site policies. Instead they are found "between the lines" and in various muddy meta posts. Which only causes confusion and frustration.

Comment: What is policy and what is recommendation at any one time is of course not clear enough, generally. But CAN it be? Unfortunately, even the question of how well this problem can be solved -- how to lay the law down while still allowing the law to evolve as it needs to -- is an involved and ongoing discussion.

Comment: I hope it's not too much noise if I say: This question and its accepted answer are good enough that they've altered my behaviour. I previously wondered about answering an exam question; I chose to answer partially. I gave them the first third clearly enough that they can do the rest similarly. In case I caused their return I should definitely go back, to advise them for next time and from now on, I will be behaving as though not answering is the policy. In some situations I might still comment, on why my answer is contingent on an improvement to the question.

Comment: In contrast, there's also the [reversal badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's site policy enforced pretty heavily at the level of the *asker*, not the *answerer*.

We handle both of these relatively the same:  downvotes and placing the question on hold.  The difference between the asker and answer is that the asker gets clamped down fairly harshly after a few downvote/close cycles, whereas the answerer only need worry about their *own* downvotes.

In essence, I've treated like a site policy to not answer poor questions.  On principle I'd hope others would do the same, but even then that's a slightly murky subject.

Comment: One can presumably get answer ban if most of the answers are of bad quality and it somewhat easy to get into such state if all answers are on bad/unclear questions.

Comment: I'm tempted to divorce the possibility of punishment for answering bad/unclear questions with answer bans @AlexeiLevenkov because they're significantly more uncommon. I won't disagree that one can get an answer ban because they answer bad questions, but getting a question ban because you ask bad questions is the far more pressing issue.  I did say answers were a bit murky because, regardless of what one can do short of getting it deleted, answers can still accrue reputation regardless of what they're attached to.

Comment: I am persuaded by that weighting, which I wasn't aware of, that it's not too harsh to answerers for this to be the site policy.

Comment: relevant for answering poor questions: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/95?m=497440#497440

Comment: I don't see how it answer the question ("Is it a policy or not?") Or at best it is misleading: this question is about *answers* to "bad" questions. Your answer implies that people who provide correct answers should be punished completely ignoring (linked in the question) Brad Larson♦ answer: [*"going after people who are providing good answers to "bad" questions is counterproductive"*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348634/4279). [Shog9♦ answer (linked there) also worth a read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348626/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian So, you're arguing that this is a suggestion, not policy? I'm inclined to agree based on the links you supply, actually. Incidentally, if that's the case, it seems like SO should consider rephrasing the document to clarify which things are actually site policy and which ones aren't.