# Preventing new users from answering poor questions

Tags: feature-request, answers

As a user who is mainly active in answering questions, I see a lot of new users (let's say 500 reputation or less) that are looking for questions that seem easy to answer. Then, they unleash many similar answers and try to be the first to get the accepted answer. Among these questions, some are very poorly asked and get downvoted quickly.

Still, a lot of misguided answers are given anyway in efforts to raise reputation. At the end of the day, the poorly asked questions are getting more attention than they deserve and the result is *bad answers*. Also, the time put into writing those answers probably won't pay back, since none of them have a decent chance of being accepted if the question is poorly written in the first place.

I think that a way to discourage poorly written questions (and subsequent poorly written answers) would be to prevent new users under some thresholds to post an answer to a poor question. For an example, let it be 500- reputation and a question below -5.

Users that are more familiar with Stack Overflow will more likely wait for the question to improve before answering, enforcing the question to get improved in order to get answers. Failing to improve the question will probably mean no answers and closing. Eventually, that could convince new users that if they don't put time in asking questions, people won't put time into answering them.

What do you guys think?

---

Update:

As pointed out by some, the problem isn't related to new users only. There are also high reputation users that are abusing the reputation system by answering poor questions that seem easy for them. For that matter, as suggested by @MarounMaroun, a solution to that problem, if it exists, would also need to consider high reputation users.

Comment: The effect of this is generally achieved by closing. It *could* take away the sense of urgency for closevoting, which could be a negative side effect.

Comment: I think we should block users with *high* reputation answering such questions... Unfortunately there are many users who only care about reputation rather than the community.

Comment: For each negative point, the threshold is increased by 100. Even with that though I still think the question would end up being closed as most questions that receive downvotes like -5 are _most likely_ off-topic and are unlikely to be improved

Comment: Yeah so they'll upvote the question and then post their answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster Pretty sure they're doing that already. Still, we could look at the number of downvotes, rather than the score, to counter that risk.

Comment: Just a couple of minutes ago I saw question in the [tag:swift] tag asking what the `&` operator does. Obviously a dupe, no research effort at all, the question's currently closed and at -6. Still, it has three answers, all of them by 8k+ / 15k+ users. Just a confirmation of @MarounMaroun's comment. (I'm not going to link the question and throw the users under the bus)

Comment: @Keiwan for the higher-rep users it's sometimes the fatigue of [the uphill battle I described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310698/stack-overflow-fatigue-has-your-usage-motivation-dropped-off/310709#310709). After encountering a handful of low-effort questions which get answered with low-quality answers by low-rep users before the community has had a chance to deal with the question, you get so tired that you just stop doing moderatorish stuff and answer the first next question you happen to click on. I'm not condoning this behavior, but I do understand it sometimes.

Comment: I once dupe hammered a *question* asked by a 100k+ rep user to another question that had been *answered* by the same 100k+ user, which was in turn a poorly asked question and should have been duped to something asked previously. So the problem is not limited to low rep users, though it may be exaggerated there.

Comment: It is indeed depressing to see a 50k+user answering such multi-dup questions. I suppose that's how they got 50k+ rep:(

Comment: I agree with @MarounMaroun, it shouldn't just be for new users but also high rep users. How about a penalizing system that targets answers to posts that have been closed for low quality, discouraging them from answering low quality posts?

Comment: @rottenoats [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/6214222) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299353/penalty-for-answering-help-vampire-questions-or-reward-closure?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Keiwan those are some great questions and answers. Has there been anything done on the matter since? It's been roughly a year since those questions were created.

Comment: @rottenoats Not that I know of. The biggest problem is - as the answers to those questions also point out - that penalizing users for these things is generally not as straightforward as it might seem and that it would end up in a mess of tons of edge cases and cases where it's not really clear who should / should not be penalized.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I've called out high-rep users doing this and they usually say something along the lines of "I like answering questions". So, not necessarily for the rep, just wanting to be helpful. Of course, they're ruining the site, but why let that slow anyone down?

Comment: Whenever I ask the OP to improve his question and I see someone provide an answer, I feel the need to challenge it and to ask why his answer should ever be good if the question isn't. The problem with that is if the new user feels peer pressure he could be tempted to delete his own answer which can work towards a ban for him. Especially if he hadn't posted many answers yet, deleting his own answer seems to be the worst thing he can do to fix the situation. So I end up challenging them *sometimes*, but I mainly want to help them write better answers, not to bash on them or getting them banned.

Comment: @Frederik.L `the new user feels peer pressure he could be tempted to delete his own answer which can work towards a ban for him` that wouldn't in any way contribute toward them getting a post ban.  That's not going to be a problem in that situation at all.

Comment: Related: [Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Comment: @MartinJames "It is indeed depressing to see a 50k+user answering such multi-dup questions." I wonder why it is depressing? Even though you or me maybe wouldn't do it (and maybe would end up with less unicorn points), you actually have to admire the stamina of these 50k+ users doing that. They do a lot of (kind of unnecessary) work and totally for free. On the plus side, they relieve the burden of finding dupe targest quickly. We know that questions get answered. We could discuss if it is actually really bad to answer dups when you are aware it's a dup, but still I do not find it depressing.

Comment: @Trilarion You may not find it depressing that people don't tire of engaging in inappropriate behavior, but I'd certainly say it's rather understandable.  I don't exactly have a lot of admiration for people that go out of their way to, "for free" engage in harmful behaviors for extended periods of time.  It'd be *much* better if they *did* give up engaging in bad behavior.  Of course it's *actually* be admirable if they were continuing to provide *valuable* content for a long period of time.

Comment: @Servy You see it as harmful but towards the questioners this is rather helpful. Maybe in the long run it's harmful but then the solution is simply to void all rep upon closure of a question. You said yourself there were lengthy discussions about it and this is not the case currently. So maybe the community just doesn't want to punish them for they harmful-helpful behavior.

Comment: @Trilarion You are correct that people enjoy rewarding people for engaging in said harmful behavior, and they *don't* get punished for engaging in the harmful behavior, and that's certainly a bit part of why people keep doing it.  That is part of what makes this depressing; knowing that lots of people are actively supporting harmful behavior, not just that some people are continually engaging in it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the reputation is voided when the question is deleted.

Comment: @DavidG Oh god, that out-does the "[one line answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44874464/1663383)" I saw from a 250k rep user that was posted after three other fantastic answers and when I commented that it was a low quality answer (literally "this is what happens") without explaining why it happened, his reply was along the lines of "I don't see the problem."

Comment: So how should someone respond to answers like the one @Draco18s points out or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45377949/5894241)? I don't think any of the flag would fit it..

Comment: @Frederik.L Sometimes.  If the post has a score of +3, and went 2(?) months without being deleted, then no, the reputation is kept.  Most of these types of questions don't end up meeting those criteria, but some do.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if a negative score on a question also start to affect the score on the answers. So if a question has -20 and an answer +5, the net result is that the answer is still considered to have a score of -15. I mean right now answerers don't really have to care much about the state of the question, so what if they really really should care?

Comment: @Gimby I think that if question score directly affects the score of the answer we might see an increase in people up voting every single question they answer. Some already do that so their answers get visibility, but I think a lot more would do it if that results in higher reputation. Sure enough we could ignore his own up vote, if any.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is not a behavior unique to low rep users.  Lots of people with lots of rep answer bad questions, many of them regularly.  Only stopping low rep users from answering bad questions isn't going to fix the problem.

Next, a big part of the problem here is that these types of bad answers come out *very quickly*.  This is a type of problem that closure is *designed* to solve.  In theory these types of bad questions would just get closed before people could answer them, and then they couldn't post bad answer.  In practice though the questions just get answered before enough people are able to vote to close the question.  You're going to run into the same problem here; people will just get their answers in before the question is able to attract enough downvotes.

So yes, while this is a problem, your proposed change is unlikely to do much to actually address it.

Comment: the real solution is for the community to downvote low quality answers, though there's a disincentive to do so

Comment: @aw04 And also a culture against it, sadly, which only makes it that much more of a problem.  Too many people consider the only valid metric for voting on answers to be whether or not they're technically correct, not whether or not they're actually useful or of high quality, so an answer that's repeating the same information for the 10,000th time in unclear language with poorly designed code that violates best practices, provides an incomplete answer to the question, etc. is considered upvote worthy by most people, so long as there is no technically incorrect information in it.

Comment: Why can users gain rep from a closed question anyway? Shouldn't everyone involve lose the rep gained from questions like this?

Comment: @battery.cord It's been proposed lots of times, you're more than welcome to read through the previous proposals on the subject if you want to know why the site behaves the way it does.

Comment: @Servy yep that's the most common thing i see getting upvotes on poor questions, stupid simple answers that are technically correct but provide no real value.. and those are often the high rep users

Comment: @aw04 "the real solution is for the community to downvote low quality answers" I wonder though if answers to low quality questions have to be low quality answers. Maybe there are high quality answers to low quality questions. I tend to judge answers independently of the question. Also "technically correct but provide no real value" I have problems imagining this, is there an example for something technically correct but not providing real value?

Comment: @Trilarion i agree, should judge independently and it's possible to have a good answer to a bad question, but i imagine there is correlation between good questions/good answers

Comment: @Trilarion It's theoretically possible, but *very* rare.  The overwhelming majority of answers to bad quesitons are not useful, and often the problems with the answer are a direct result of problems in the question.  It's *impossible* to evaluate an answer independantly of the question.  You can determine if an answer is factually correct devoid of the question, but not if it's actually useful.  Most people tend to upvote bad answers to bad questions, not just the [rare] good answers to bad questions.

Comment: @aw04 You don't judge an answer *independantly* of the question, because the quality of the question in inexorably tied to the quality of the answer.  Instead, you vote on the answer based on the usefulness of the answer (recognizing that the usefulness of the answer is affected by the question).  If the answer is so good that it's able to overcome the quality problems of the question, then by all means, upvote it, but if an answer isn't useful because of problems with the question *the answer still isn't useful* and you should vote accordingly.

Comment: @Servy yes, fair point

Comment: @Trilarion The unlikeliness of an answer to be good if the question isn't, is that a good answer needs an equally good question to be reached easily. Someone might have an awesome answer to *potato* but he is probably the only one lucky enough to read it.

Comment: How about _chips_ with _ketchup++_ (I nearly forgot that it has to be a post-increment in this case despite it normally being the case that pre-increments are optimal)? 8-)

Comment: @Frederik.L Seeing how many sufficiently good answers even bad questions get I would say that probably many people don't really care if their (sufficiently good) answers (to potato) are read often. That's one of the effects mentioned in this answer. Don't ask me why people are so generous, I don't know.

Comment: @Servy From what I've read, there is a need to quickly closevote poor questions. Given that, is it fair to instantly closevote a question that needs improvement to be good, and reopen it if it becomes good enough?

Comment: @Trilarion Then those answers *aren't actually useful answers*.  An answer that *could* be a useful answer if the people that it could help actually found it, but that *won't be found by those users* isn't a helpful answer.

Comment: @Frederik.L [That's always been my position, yes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/1159478).

Comment: @Servy It clears the confusion around how long to wait for a question to improve. More people adopting this practice would be a decent way to prevent bad answers to bad questions from appearing and addresses the mentioned problem in a way. That does it. Thanks!

Comment: @Frederik.L So yes, many people *don't* close questions right away even if they think the question merits closure, but the problem is that even if people did, it still takes 5 people with the close vote privilege to do so, so it's still quite easy to get answers in under that.

Comment: How about putting a question into a kind of pending state when it gets three close-votes, preventing answers until 48 hours have passed, at which point either it will have gotten the remaining two close-votes and been closed, or not gotten them, meaning it's sort-of-OK.

Comment: @torazaburo Personally I'd say that if you feel confident enough to actually lock the question from answers for 48 hours after 3 close votes then  you're confident enough to just close the question after 3 close votes.  Regular closure is *already* designed to be temporary and reversible.

Comment: @ I'd say if you are confident even before any close vote is given, close it too. We can safely assume that the OP won't improve his question ever if he can work around doing that. Then, if he does manage to improve it, you can do something about it. What we see in real life is people being in a hurry, dumping questions and waiting for "good enough" answers. There are not so many OPs that will come back to really improve their question.

Answer (score -4):

Would there be any merit in preventing a question from being ***answered*** for a time inversely proportional in some way to the reputation of the asker - but still allowing editing/commenting on the question before that time has elapsed?  This might help to reduce the incidence of "dumb" question getting "dumber" answers because they could be *improved* (or closed off) before *anyone* gets a chance to answer at a cost of the inexperienced questioner not getting instant gratification or rather a quick response.

If I ask a question on SE it is surely a given that I might not get the most useful response within minutes, hours, hell even months (though that is a flag that I might not have been asking something that anyone wants to bother to answer!)

I suppose this could also be done by not awarded any reputation from any *answers* including allowing the question to be "answered" until the time out - until that point they could all be greyed-out as poor answers get to be with down-votes.

*Update in reply to first few comments:*

- Nope I was wasn't aware of [triage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triage) - that does seem to be specific to SO which isn't my "primary" SE site. 8-/
- Considering the other comments - perhaps then the alternative - that all answers are considered provisional and do not gain any reputation to the respected parties until the question has "survived" to the "time out" might be more palatable.

  What would need to be different compared to how things are now is that the question can be closed *without any reputation being awarded* even if there *are* answers. Whilst this might be a little unwelcome to inexperienced answerers who dive in and try to answer a poor question it seems the least worst way to prevent sub-par questions and answers from benefiting from the current system.  Compared to my initial suggestion I guess that there could be a separate discussion as to whether the (provisional) voting for each answer should be visible before the time-out - the disadvantage is that the original asker of even a good question really won't know what the consensus of the best answer is during that period so if they want an answer quickly they will be out of luck - the advantage is that votes at that stage might be more based on the opinions of viewers of the answer (though that still leaves the viewer open to vote also on who the poster of that answer is) rather than giving "me too" votes.

Comment: are you aware of [meta-tag:triage] review system at Stack Overflow?

Comment: The problem with this is that we want (the good) questions to be answered as quickly as possible. Also it would be frustrating to read a question and not being able to answer it right away.

Comment: Totally agree. Some very good answers can be given straight away if the question recalls a past experience to the poster. When that person gets by we want that answer quickly so there is no trials and errors from people who didn't manage to solve the issue before.

Comment: Preventing new users that can provide a good answer seems unfair to them. A new comer with a good answer in mind should be able to post it as soon as he figures it out and get reputation from it, just like a reputed user would do. The mentioned problem in my question was about preventing them to post answers that are unlikely to be good. But as pointed in Servy's answer, the new comers aren't the only ones. There is still experimented users who post bad answers to get easy reputation. Then, a way to prevent that to happen is to close bad questions the faster you can before bad answers arrive.

Answer (score -8):

Is SO some kind of club? Has it special rules apart from [behavior model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)?

No. It's a community which is open for anybody. If most of its members require some rules (like this post seems to be for) then at some time it will become a special, more restricted, community, AKA "club". May be "private club".

That isn't desired, right?

The bad thing of being so open is that there are plenty of bad questions and bad answers. But also the opposite. Like any other thing in life.

Using the current up/down vote system seems a "democratic" system. Democracy is not perfect, we know. But gives people the freedom (or the illusion) to tell what is right or wrong.

Some people uses the reputation of the guy who answers as the criterion. Others the number of up/down votes. Others if the answer solves the problem or not. Others a combination of several factors. Others...

Despite the reputation, the poorness of the question or the answer, **the point is that SO works pretty well as it is now** with the [current rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Smart people gets enough from this site. Dumb people get almost nothing from anything (but still the right of learn and improve exists for everybody). Again, so is mankind.

Over-restrictive rules is like trying to stop a storm with your hands.

### EDIT

I'm not against rules. I'm against of so many rules. My opinion is that the already existing rules, as expressed in the help and tour pages are enough for most people to tell between right/wrong/useful. I'm very sure that more rules implies also less succeed. There's no app, book or man-made thing that is perfect. Current system gives a good criterion. No need a perfect one.

Comment: _"Has it special rules apart from behavior model?"_ ... We have _tons_ of rules that keep our quality high, most of them rules I don't see on sites outside the Stack Exchange network. If that's _not_ what you mean, please edit to clarify.

Comment: There is another page of rules that you forgot, [ones specific to answering questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). See, in particular, the admonition to "Answer well-asked questions".

Comment: @Kendra: *tons* of rules. No. The ones at help pages, an example is the sub-link Cody Gray shown. I just posted the first link.

Comment: Just because SE is open for all people to contribute doesn't mean *all types of contributions* are welcome.  There are lots of rules of *what* can be contributed, even though everyone is allowed to contribute acceptable things.

Comment: @Servy "acceptable things" is the key. Appart from the rules at help pages, the up/dowm vote system express very well what the community thinks about a question or an answer. Do we need more? I think we don't.

Comment: @Ripi2 Clearly we do, given how often people are contributing low quality content.  That's the whole point of this question.

Comment: @Servy OK. Set one million rules. Make SO an experts-only site. You ruined the goal of SO, even you did achieved high-quality content.

Comment: What do you think the "goal" of this site is?

Comment: Hint: it's not to have lots of people contributing low quality content.

Comment: Quoting [goal](https://stackexchange.com/tour) "experts and enthusiasts". There are a few experts but lot of enthusiasts. With just the formers this site would not succeed. Low quality is just a little price to pay for.

Comment: @Ripi2 That first sentence is not the "goal" of SE. The second one is: *"We build libraries of high-quality questions and answers (...)"*. See also [What is Stack Overflow's goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)

Comment: ... and that implies that it must be possible to remove low-quality ones - but it seems that the presence of answers (either _good_ or _bad_) to _poor_ questions stops _that_.

Comment: [Are we being elitist? Is there something wrong with that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262446)

Comment: @Ripi2 StackOverflow basically has only one rule and this is "don't put garbage into it". This rule is however subdivided into many more rules so that people know what it's all about and comes to change their behavior if they miss the point. Once you get the idea it's fairly easy to follow that rule. We don't promote Jesus stuff or private rituals but quality has become a priority over the last years, which is good. More and more people are getting into programming and we must ensure that they do it right. That rule isn't perfectly honored yet, though.

Comment: @Frederik.L I absolutely agree with you, and with Caswell, and others. The thing on my answer is "current rules, good; excess of rules, bad". But most people saddly seems to think I'm against quality. Ironically I've been the Quality Manager several years due to my skill in fixing designs, procedures and behaviors. Wrong code, maths and other matters are easy to fix with a bit of knowledge. Humans require much more time and flexibility and even so only a few percentaje succeed. A not-low level of garbaje is unavoidable.

Answer (score -15):

StackOverflow questions and answers have helped me code more than anything and every time I find the solution to my problems here all I want to do is to find a way to thank the community, but I never could because of my reputation I couldn't even upvote.

Of course I could give back to the community by answering questions or asking good ones, but so far all my questions have already been answered by previous posts and a lot of unanswered questions (that aren't dupes) are really hard for a begginer to answer.

So what's left for begginers? Watch the recent questions page and answer an easy question the fast as they can. Well maybe some bad questions were answered, but at the end what happened? Someone who was to lazy to make their reaserch got It's solution and someone earned some reputation.

You can argue that this beginner's strategy makes lazy questions more frequent and lowers the forum quality. However, as pointed out, that's not just a strategy just for beginners and also the voting system is the correct way to tell good and bad questions apart, *voting is more important than restricting users*.

For me, anyone that wants to actively contribute to the community needs to have at least 500 points of reputation so they can freely upvote and downvote and in that way split what is worth form what is not.

**What I'm trying to say here is**: It's already hard for a begginer to earn some reputation here and restricting even more what can be done in the site is going to make it even harder for newcomers to join. Answering easy/bad questions is fastest way beginners can contribute to the community in the voting process.

Comment: The purpose of the site is not to ensure that anyone and everyone is able to get lots of rep, even if they're incapable of providing anything of value.  The purpose of the site is to create a useful repository of knowledge.  If someone isn't able to actually contribute anything useful to the site we don't *want* them being rewarded for performing actions that are harmful to the site.  If you're grateful that SO has helped you so much then *make the site better, not worse*; don't make it harder for other people to be helped by SO.

Comment: I agree, the purpose is not to ensure that anyone and everyone is able to get lots of rep, that's not what I meant. But it shouldn't be **harder** to achieve the minimum to start voting up and down, as voting questions and answers is more beneficial than answering bad questions is harmful (in my humble 58 rep opnion).

Comment: @DaniloFavato. You only need **15** rep to upvote, and that will also allow you to flag comments (amongst other things). With **20** rep, you can talk in chat, and **50** rep will allow you to comment anywhere. So all that a beginner needs to do is ask one or two decent questions to gain access to most of the features you allude to. Even downvoting only requires **125** rep. The best way to get the rep you want is to *ask a good question*.

Comment: I think that part of what separated StackOverflow from Yahoo Groups is making it hard to get started without knowing the rules. In fact, a common mistake by new comers is they ask questions for themselves instead of asking them for the community. Accordingly, answers to selfish questions have low chances to help the community and will get down voted. Acting for the community will get you started and you will earn reputation.

Comment: Also note that asking and answering questions are not the only ways to gain reputation on SO. You can get +2 rep for every approved edit and if I'm not mistaken you can gain a total of 1000 rep purely through such approved edits. Editing questions by improving their formatting, grammar and other fixable problems is a direct and very effective way of contributing to the community.

Comment: @DaniloFavato It should be hard to earn the privilege to vote posts up and down if you're incapable of actually providing useful content, yes.  It should be (and is) very easy to earn that privilege if you're able to provide useful contributions.

Comment: I actually agree with this answer. It's good enough as it is and the proposed change would make the thing rather worse not better. Thanks for that answer.

Comment: My answer has a lot in common with Servy's. We both agree that restricting low rep users will not address the problem because it's no just them that do this kind of thing. A lot of what I said was misinterpreted.. I can be my lack of English fluency, but I wonder if it has something to do with my rep. Maybe people just assumed that I'm one of the newcomers that ruin the site or maybe that's the way to tell me meta is not the place for new users. Well just my thoughts anyway

Comment: I think Servy's comment above, with almost as many upvotes as your answer has downvotes, probably explains the downvotes better than rep bias.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. In his comment he says that "The purpose of the site is not to ensure that anyone and everyone is able to get lots of rep". I didn't say that anywhere in my answer, but somehow that's what it was understood. If it was inferred than that conclusion is somewhere in what I wrote or in how I am viewed.

Comment: @DaniloFavato. You claim that it's hard for beginners to earn enough rep to participate in voting: but that is simply not true. If you make obviously false claims like that on meta, you will get downvotes.

Comment: What is *hard* is subjective. It's not a false claim, it's just one you disagree.

Comment: @DaniloFavato. As I pointed out above, you only need **15** rep to upvote. You could get that with eight accepted edits, or two or three upvotes on questions/answers. So it is clearly *not* hard, unless you aren't willing to make *any* effort to learn how to use the site properly.

Comment: _"I didn't say that anywhere in my answer"_ Your summary at the end of your answer -- "**What I'm trying to say here is:** (bold in original) -- says that it's hard for beginners to get rep, and it shouldn't be made harder. If you're being misunderstood, then please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Actually, only *seven* accepted edits are needed to upvote, because everyone starts with 1 rep point.

Comment: I don't think saying it "shoudn't be **harder**" is the same as  saying it should be **ensured** to everyone. It is if you assume the way it is now it is too easy and ensures everyone gets lot of rep, than why not raise the bar? Make it harder for newcomers.

Comment: 15 reputation is 1 accepted answer. It's really not that hard.

Answer (score -20):

Who defines what is **poor**? I personally like @Danilo Favato's answer, but as we can all see, lots of down votes for him. It's not just me and a handful of people who have a problem with SO's methods of defining "poor" questions, an [article](https://hackernoon.com/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) on Hackernoon covers issues I've encountered with SO (I've summarized them below, in accordance with the SO guidelines).

- Stack Overflow hates new users: Beginners come on this site because they want to learn. Is it so bad if they ask questions without showing their own attempts? I'm sure I'm not the only user on here who is happy to help others get started.
- Stack Overflow also hates most other users: How does SO ensure that more technical questions aren't downvoted because the users don't understand the questions? High-level questions may not have simple code snippets. I've put up advanced questions with snippets and gotten downvoted, and without snippets with the same voting.
- The reign of privileged trolls: I understand that some people may be unclear about the high and mighty rules of SO, or may want to get a quick coding solution to a problem without going into the theoretical background. Why is that looked down upon? Computer science is full of papers that have no practical use. Also, just because you found a user who isn't following the guidelines, does that give you the right to be condescending?

So here's my take. You want to keep SO high-quality and have people actually use the website? Then stop worrying about "poor" questions and start worrying about users with "poor" social skills who will create a lot of negative vibe.

Comment: there are certainly issues with fuzzy question guidelines and members of the community who take things too far, but the flip side is you often need to know something to be able to ask a decent question. it wouldn't make sense for me to go on a forum for physicists and start asking random questions because i want to build a rocket ship when i have no idea what i'm doing

Comment: "Stack Overflow hates new users" No, SO hates *bad content*.  New users that post great content are received well.  Users that post bad content *whether new or old* have that content received poorly. "Is it so bad if they ask questions without showing their own attempts?" In many situations, yes, yes it is.  SO isn't a "do my homework for me because I can't be bothered to do it myself" site, and these questions hurt *everyone*, including the one asking them.  "[...] downvoted because the users don't understand the questions?"  If the questions are unclear then *they merit downvotes*.

Comment: "Why is that looked down upon?" Because it's harmful to the site, and the user, and everyone involved.  "Then stop worrying about 'poor' questions" That's the attitude that basically every single other QA site has taken, and the result is that they're all full of crap, nobody likes using them, they don't actually help people get answers to their questions, and the experts have moved on mass to SO instead.  If you want to interact with a site that has that policy *go almost literally anywhere besides SO* and that'll be the policy.

Comment: There's many thriving communities out there, are you sure SO is the only good community on the internet?

Comment: @HammanSamuel. Without wishing to be too provocative: if there are so many viable alternatives to SO, why are you still here?

Comment: @HamSam Why do new users hate StackOverflow? Please don't hate, just be awesome (and get reputation).

Comment: you might want to take a look at [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) because this article discusses who defines what is poor at Stack Overflow. "We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A; system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it..."

Comment: @Servy en masse*

Comment: Regarding "*High-level questions may not have simple code snippets*": Every high level coding question is based on a problem that can be reduced to a *MCVE*. It does not mean, that the *MCVE* needs to be a maximum of 4 lines. The problem is, most questions throwing only a code dump into the question block. If the question is about best practises, we have other communities for it in Stack Exchange (cr.SE, se.SE)

Comment: `Is it so bad if they ask questions without showing their own attempts?`  Yes. It is specifically defined in [HOW TO ASK A GOOD QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which overall translates to *"ask a question that describes the problem clearly, what your attempt to solve it is, and what you experienced for why it didn't work."* If they don't meet this set of criteria, then they deserve the downvote, because it is a bad question. Even when I was new, I never felt that "stack overflow hates new users". My questions were pretty much upvoted with two exceptions, rightfully.

Comment: I made my account specifically to ask a question on StackOverflow. My question was upvoted because I actually took the time to take the tour and read through the help center because I needed it to be answered. StackOverflow doesn't hate new users. They hate users that don't even bother to try to write a good question.

Comment: Who says StackOverflow hates new users? Visit [new users](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers) tab and see their reputation.