# Mechanism for preventing users from deleting once they get a solution in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-questions

Tangentially related to [this question,](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353833/preventing-new-users-from-answering-poor-questions) but recently I've been presented with a situation in which I spent a while asking for clarifications from a user on a question in order to better answer them.

This is typically the process for lower-quality questions, I've found, but I frequently see meta posts about turning low-quality questions into higher quality questions through edits and clarifications.

Unfortunately, in my case, the user **seemed** to get to their answer through the discussion in the comments, and, having come to the solution, deleted their question instead of posting an answer to the issue they were experiencing.

In this particular case, I believe there **was** a question to be answered still remaining, but the asker **seemed** to leave with no comments after they came to a conclusion.

---

**My question is this:** *Is there any way that we can prevent users from deleting as soon as they get an answer?* It seems like a way to rob users of time and reputation if they were giving a genuine attempt to help.

As I understand it, you cannot delete a question after an answer has been posted without sufficient approval, but that feels like anyone involved in helping the user come to a solution before then has just wasted their time.

This always seems like an inherent risk with answering questions, especially if they're lower quality, and I could always ask the question myself and answer it, provided I somehow saved all the details of the question before it was deleted (I didn't), but it still feels like a way to "game" the system.

Comment: You are correct, that is an inherent risk. And a good reason why many of us help until a certain point and then *cease helping*. There is nothing to be gained an much time to be lost.

Comment: Why would we want to keep low quality questions on the site? If it is a high-quality question that would really improve the site (which rarely get self deleted), then a moderator or some community members can undelete it.

Comment: As long as your answer doesn't have upvotes you are at the mercy of the OP. You could try a mod flag if you feel the question is deleted where it has value. In that case a mod might undelete and if the OP has a pattern of doing the same "trick" often they might receive some stern talking to.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yeah, that's why I referenced the other thread, that seems to be a theme in the comments there too.

Comment: @rene that sounds like reasonable recourse, if a mod were particularly perceptive enough to notice that pattern. Also, does that mean I could've just up-voted the question to prevent them from deleting preemptively?

Comment: Try not to get too invested in a question unless it's above certain minimum quality. Spending a lot of time and energy with comments trying to get someone to edit their question into shape sometimes works, but **many** times it doesn't. Look for questions that are already good or close to be in good shape. You'll get better results.

Comment: @ErinB no, an **ANSWER** need an upvote. You can't vote on your own answer. At least not yet. If you make a mod aware of the possible pattern, they have no trouble finding it.

Comment: Small correction - you cannot delete a question after an answer has been posted with a score of 1 or more, or if 2+ answers have been posted regardless of score. If there's only one answer and it's at 0 or negative score, you can still delete your question. The reasoning for these thresholds is that the asker should not have more say in keeping a question on the site than *multiple* other people, but vs one other person, the asker should retain authority to self-delete without approval.

Comment: @ErinB If I'm looking at the Q I think you're referring to, it does look like you were hand holding them through a debug session in the comments and the question itself wasn't getting any better or useful for anyone else as it were quite specific... I'd also guess that since most of the conversation was ~1 day ago, the OP finally worked it out themselves and therefore decided to remove it... As others have said, I'd advise to recognise yourself getting drawn in like that, and unless you feel the question can be edited into shape and answered (maybe by yourself) - not to worry too much :)

Comment: @JonClements yeah lesson learned on that, I mistook the user editing the question as an attempt at clarification. Still though, it should be encouraged for them to provide an answer, or edit their question in a way that accurately reflected their problem. All the same, my concern is less about my Q and more about a theoretical user gaming the system.

Comment: @ErinB given they're quite an experienced user... like I said - maybe they realised what they were asking was actually straight-forward (after time thinking/discussing), isn't useful to others, and thus didn't want to invest time bringing the question up to date and answering it, when it might attract closure/down votes on both the question and answer and ultimately end up gone anyway...

Comment: Just a slight comment on your "_robbed of time and rep_" line Erin, keep in mind that that time is gone regardless if the OP deletes the question or not. However, it wasn't wasted as a result, you still helped the OP get to the bottom of their issue and if you treat your time on SO as exactly that, some time allotted to help others, then really you've lost nothing. However, you did miss out on those sweet, sweet rep-points-which-we-are-all-really-here-for-but-not-meant-to-admit-to and for that I can only laugh, ha, more rep for me as I answer question I sense will not get deleted! :D :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was a mistake to engage in an extensive conversion in comments. That is not the purpose of comments. It was a mistake to try to provide one-to-one help. That is not the purpose of this site.

What you should have done was vote-to-close the question, with a suitable close reason (or *flag* the question with the reason that it should be closed, if you do not have the vote-to-close privilege). If you wanted to be extra helpful, you could have provided *one* comment  indicating what the asker had to provide or clarify. Then you should have **moved on**. Then you would not have wasted anyone's time.

Comment: @ErinB you may not be able to close *vote*... but you can still *flag* the post and select "should be closed" and then the reason why which'll put the post in review for others to decide whether to cast their close votes on it

Answer (score 7):

People shouldn't be posting answers in the comment section in the first place. If they want to answer, they should actually write an answer.

Given that there's already a system in place for preventing people from deleting questions that already have answers, I don't see a need for any change here.