# What is the appropriate course of action towards a user that is consistently answering off-topic, low quality, and duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, downvotes, vote-to-close, low-quality-posts

If you browse [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), chances are that you've come across a user that answered 1,000 questions in the past month, most of which ended up being closed. Most of these questions are closed within minutes, but this user is making it their personal mission to write an answer to any and every question (averaging more than 15 answers per day since their account creation), most of the time receiving no vote, and often writing outright ***wrong*** answers (frequently voted down to -3).

Browsing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) feels like playing cat and mouse, where close votes need to cast as fast as possible because someone will immediately jump on the possibility to farm easy reputation points from a user who doesn't know how to append a list. As a result, it feels almost useless to go through the process of finding the right duplicate because there will be at least one answer and the automatic cleanup script won't be triggered.

I'm using my privilege to vote as often as I feel appropriate, for instance when said person answers a question about a typo when there are already two close votes, but it's not a deterrent when offset by a new contributor that upvotes and accepts an answer to their duplicate question.

I flagged this user for moderator attention, but no action was taken. It's understandable because these are not severe violations, and that someone would need to browse [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to really know what's going on. This user has been banned twice in the past month for vote fraud and sock puppeting, but my concern is about all the other "unwritten rule" breaking that counters all the efforts to keep the site clean.

**tl;dr** Is there no recourse against users who consistently violate rules of etiquette, assuming that they are not deterred by several downvotes every day?

Comment: _"it's useless to vote to close because there will be some form of answer in the first few minutes"_ It's not really useless. If the question is VLQ and heavily downvoted, it's very likely that it will be deleted within 48 hours or so after being closed. If the answer is also a poor one (and voted down to -3 as you say), it won't prevent the question from being deleted (or make it require more delete-votes).

Comment: That's why we need a delete queue! Or anything that make us delete more and more to make the effort of such users useless.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I thought you couldn't delete when there's an upvoted answer. There's an upvoted answer every time a new user upvotes someone reminding them that they forgot to define a variable

Comment: you can always delete closed question after 2 days whataver the answers/uvpotes/accepted/bounties ... you cannot delete your own question when there is upvoted answers

Comment: Isn't the problem mostly with questions rather than the answerer? Why are these questions not downvoted, closed and deleted sooner?

Comment: Do we have a rule about answering low-quality questions? Are they actually breaking any official rule? Can you prove that they have ill intent?

Comment: @Dharman Because the Python tag is full of people not interested in closing questions. Basic, garbage questions get upvoted, and people leave all kinds of answers to them.

Comment: @Dharman You told me once that answering LQ questions is not encouraged.

Comment: @10Rep `Not encouraged != breaking rules`. It _is_ indeed a discouraged behavior though.

Comment: @10Rep Encouraged, no. But is there a rule against it? Also, no.

Comment: @Dharman It encourages users to write LQ questions, and misinforms them about the site. Isn't that enough.

Comment: A good way to keep this objective and shine a light on this behavior, without violating rules, would be to post an SEDE query on which users get the most rep per month on questions in [python] tag asked by users with (say) rep < 125, or rep < 100.

Comment: @10Rep Low-quality questions are an encouragement it itself, which is why we need to close them and delete them. If you see a flow of low-quality answers it is only one more sign that the question should be closed and probably deleted. You can inform the answerer that it is a waste of their time to answer such question, because sooner or later either roomba or us will delete them and the rep gain will be undone.

Comment: There is much more than one such user in [python], and some have been around for months or years. It's more scaleable, more generalizable and much less likely to be construed as violating rules (and get this valuable question deleted) if we stick to observations based on SEDE data, rather than inferred motives etc. Or just do the last 7 days, last 30 days, last 90 days if you like?

Comment: SEDE-based data will work fine on all users who've been active in [python] tag for longer than 7/30/90 days, which is 99.9+% of users. That's perfectly fine.We are not discussing any specific user, end of story. Not even giving the appearance of doing that.

Comment: 10Rep: yes it totally will. An SEDE query will show which users get the most rep per month on questions in [python] tag asked by users with (say) rep < 125, or rep < 100. We could even rank it by question outcome (deleted, closed-as-dupe, closed-as-needs-more-details, etc.; this is hard to do automatically, since deleted questions won't show up, but it can be done) **Then, people can semi-manually inspect those Q&A to see what's going on, and they can make inferences about which users are rep-farming LQ questions. If there is any violating behavior, they can flag it.** That's your solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Comment: Just downvote the posts. don't think about it. it's easy. There's far too many people doing this for singling out one user to be of much use. They'll get their 10k, or 20k, rep, realize it's useless, then move on.

Comment: Exact same struggle but with javascript tag. Doesn't matter how fast you close the question, there's always 2 answers because the users started typing before it was closed. You downvote the Q & A, it gets upvoted immediately. You tell them not to asnwer obvious duplciates, you risk revenge downvotes. I vote to delete them and only a small percentage of them actually gets deleted. The tag is littered with low quality duplicates & typos and I'm honestly tired.

Comment: While I agree that the behavior is a problem, I worry the case is not strengthened by exaggerating the numbers involved. [The largest number of questions answered by any single user in the last 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) is not quite 350. Regardless, the imbalance between score and answer count on that page clearly demonstrates that some users have room for improvement.

Comment: @IanCampbell The numbers on that page are an underestimation of the total number that are posted. Many of the answers are deleted along with the low-quality and/or duplicate questions. The number of 1,000 questions in the past month is definitely obtained by rounding up, but, shockingly, mostly accurate. It is definitely not misleading in the sense of exaggerating the problem. This is as far as I want to discuss this, to avoid risking the discussion identifying or converging on a particular user. I think we'll have to take it on face value that the claims here aren't overblown.

Comment: Voting is faster than writing an answer. Vote on content not users. Long term you'll see that these "contributors" disappear while the ones voting stay ...

Comment: For folks who think the Python tag is consistently low-quality, no-effort/research, [tag:pandas] is an even worse subset, with instant answers from a few high-rep users to every question regardless of quality. Looking at the [Python top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers) page, then looking at the [Pandas top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/topusers) page, I think it's reasonable to blame Pandas for much of the Python-related LQ content flooding the site. Granted, the fast top user answers in this tag are generally high quality, but the questions are often not.

Comment: Has that user ever received a comment about the attitude? Maybe the user is just not aware of it being bad and needs a hint.

Comment: @akuzminykh Yes, from what I personally saw in comments on their answers and chat, that user got notified many times. I left them some comments about technical problems in their answers, and though they initially seemed to react positively, they kept posting bad answers containing the same misinformation/bad practices. I've then started downvoting the really bad ones I encountered, but I often gave up as I feared that it might have been considered serial downvoting - and more than once, these posts got uninformed upvotes, so that feels like a lost cause...

Answer (score 21):

Continue using your moderation tools to maintain sanity on the tag. It may look like a losing battle, but we haven't gotten past September, so while they continue to answer questions, they do not get the associated rewards of such behavior.

That should be enough deterrent. If that's not enough, you can flag one of their post and ask for moderator intervention. There's a little used suspension reason called "low quality contributions". Be prepared to show evidence that the user consistently submit low quality contributions and that the system isn't kicking fast enough to cause a behavior correction.

Answer (score 12):

Don't focus on the user. Focus on the specific posts, and create a strong incentive to improve.

Here's what you can do - these are all options available to you:

- Edit the Question or Answer if you think you can salvage the material.
- Downvote the question if it is bad.
- Close-vote the question if it is closeworthy and you don't have the energy to attempt a rescue.
- Bring it to the attention of the Close Vote reviewers with a `[tag:cv-pls]`. Know the rules ([see the FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq#how-and-why-do-i-need-to-format-my-cv-pls-and-other-requests)) before you post and be prepared to defend your position, and participate in the voting activity as well, if you want their help.
- Downvote the answer if it is bad. Don't be afraid of repercussions - you are voting on the content, not the user and moderators are aware of this situation. Don't downvote the answer just because the question is bad. Don't target the user's posts. But if you see a dozen downvote-worthy posts, regardless of the user, over the course of the day, use your downvotes.
- Specifically state the problems you have with the answer in a comment. This will document your reasons for downvoting, if you so chose, and help less savvy users know the material needs improvement. It should also include constructive criticism that would help the answer improve.
- Flag for a moderator only when you have a specific and justified reason to flag. Do not flag frivolously.

Comment: I find it very difficult to "don't focus on the user" in practice. We all see moderately bad answers, and moderately inappropriate practices (e.g., answering off-topic questions while there's two close votes, while you're _way_ above 3,000), but if that user posts every now and then, you can let it slide. But when you see the same person doing that multiple times a day, it's hard to judge the situation solely based on the answer. I don't think any place on earth has that kind of unbiasedness.

Comment: @NicolasGervais The trick is to have a userscript that hides usernames.

Comment: "Don't be afraid of repercussions": hey that's my 1 rep point we're talking about here :)

Comment: This is very similar to my default course of action, and in so far I agree that is a good first approach. However, for serial offences this can get impractical – e.g. a low-quality, *very basic* question that leads to 4, 5, 6 or more low-quality answers. Trying to better everyone can get out of hand by sheer mass. Singling out the serial offending *users* can often be met by claims of bias  ("why are you picking on me? you don't complain about <other bad answer>"). This also works in other dimensions, e.g. user rejecting feedback because their other bad answers are not were not flagged/voted.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - If we are truly talking about low quality answers.  Raise the issue to the moderators.  The community moderators have it in their power, to issue a suspension, for low quality contributions.  One should of course vote to close, each and every one of these questions, that are out of scope.  The user will eventually improve their contributions or be suspended.

Comment: @SecurityHound Answers which are *formally* fine but *technically* dubious are usually not the responsibility or even capabilities of moderators. Plus, since this is about the massive volume of repeated, low-quality answers, I doubt the moderators have the sheer capabilities to handle as much. This very thread exists because it's already (almost?) too much for the volunteers using regular user moderation tools.

Answer (score -8):

It's not against the rules to answer low-quality questions. We answer questions because we think that it will be found by people in the future with a similar problem who will benefit from our answer. **You are encouraged to edit the question after answering to improve its quality**. After all, that should be your goal, to have both question and the answer of very high quality. A great answer can even save poorly written question from deletion.

If you see a low-quality question being answered then don't blame the answerer. Blame the tag experts who didn't close the question in time or blame Stack Overflow for not providing us better moderation tools to deal with the inflow of bad questions. If the answerer is a new user, then you can post a helpful comment explaining why it is not worth posting answers to unclear/off-topic/typo questions. There's a good post explaining this here: [How to deal with unclear questions and their lightning-fast ("fastest gun in the west") answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308302/1839439)

If you think the answer itself is wrong or just poorly written (no explanation, guessing at a problem, "Try this:") you can also downvote the answer. Remember that [it is **not** ok to simply downvote an answer because the question was bad quality.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255459/1839439) **It is forbidden to go through their profile page and downvote their other answers too.**

If the user has flag or close privileges already you can spend some time to instruct them when it is more appropriate to close a question rather than answering it. You were also a new user at some point and you also had to learn when to close and when to answer. Be polite!

If someone is consistently posting poorly written answers then you can involve moderators who will talk to the user and if necessary suspend them for providing low-quality content. Make sure that you properly explain why you think their contributions are harmful to the site.

Comment: *"You are encouraged to edit the question after answering to improve its quality. After all, that should be your goal, to have both question and the answer of very high quality."* No, if it's obviously a dupe, it should be closed as a dupe, immediately. This is often the case these days. And if the question's so badly-written that we can't readily tell which question(s) it's a dupe of, then it's your judgment call how much personal effort you want to spend in going to-and-fro with the user to elucidate what it's a dupe of, given that it'll likely ultimately be closed as dupe, and/or- deleted.

Comment: tl;dr: a question can be both LQ and a dupe. This is quite common in [python] these days, especially with people copying walls of boilerplate machine-learning code from tutorial sites, often ancient 2.x code. Or, people who post just a spec or challenge, no code. A question can also be so vaguely-written it's impossible to tell whether it is both LQ and a dupe. Or no-MCVE. Both of those also very common. It's quite possible that both the asker and respondent are separately breaking the rules. There is one set of tools to deal with the respondent, and another set of tools to deal with the asker

Comment: It's not just a Python problem. It's a Stack Overflow problem. I think at least 1% of new questions is still answerable. We should really do something to prevent the remaining 99%.

Comment: **The question was asked about [python] tag**, and I'm a user who spends hours every month dealing with LQ [python] questions, and my comments are based on everything I've learned. More relevant than generic tag-agnostic. I don't think you're familiar with behavior in [python] tag at all.

Comment: Yes people have been talking about the sea of duplicates (both specifically in [python] and SO in general) for a long time, and the lack of incentive for either an asker or third-party to close-as-dupe, vs cynically rep-farming the question.

Comment: In order to be able to close you have to gain reputation. You gain reputation by answering questions.

Comment: @Dharman A never-ending spiral of doom.

Comment: But what if the answerer **is** a tag-expert?

Comment: @Dharman These are interesting points and I will consider them. One thing I absolutely need to mention is that the quality of the answer usually isn't above the quality of the post. I want to clarify that in this specific situation, the answers really aren't that good, and frequently reach -3, or it takes several other users to completely transform the answer. That's an important detail. That's especially contrasting with the __duplicated__ questions, which have been perfectioned by several users for over a decade.

Comment: Nothing here except the last paragraph is actually addressing the circumstances as described in the question.

Comment: OTOH: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: "Blame the tag experts who didn't close the question in time" Oh, thanks a lot. It is bad enough that there isn't any recognition/reputation for volunteer moderation. So nice to see for a change that we should actively be *blamed* for not being able to weed out everything.

Comment: "Blame the tag experts who didn't close the question in time" I don't know about Python, but in JavaScript bad/obvious dupe questions tend to get answers within *seconds*, in the latter case often before I can even copy/paste in the dupe link to cast my vote. The tag experts simply can't work fast enough.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Then read the second part of that sentence. We need tools to prevent such questions from being asked/visible. I agree that sometimes people are faster posting answers than we can press the close button. Something should be done about it

Comment: what if the blatant dupe question is answered before anyone can find the proper duplicate?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If the answer is adding something new then it's ok, it might become a good signpost (although that answer should have been added to the original post). If the answer doesn't add anything new then it is our job to review the Q&A after two days being closed and delete if necessary. It would be nice to have a delete queue and more delete votes because they often get forgotten in the mudslide of new questions.

Comment: @Dharman - Let's be honest the answers we are talking about don't meet those qualifications of actually adding something, even if they did, the author of the answer should be answering the existing question.