# Should I answer questions that include images of code (or violate other guidelines)?

Tags: support, answers, downvotes, low-quality-posts

I came across this [C question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69764658/a-problem-with-arithmetic-operations-on-variables-in-c-language) which had code as pictures, instead of text.

I answered the question and got 2 downvotes.

Am I doing something wrong?

To be clear, I'm not asking about why I shouldn't  *ask* a question that contains images of code/errors, I'm asking about why I shouldn't *answer* those questions.

Comment: Relevant: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/11682469)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**You should not answer questions that do not meet [our minimum standards for a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These questions should be [*closed*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) instead.** To facilitate the closure of such questions, you should flag them: use the "needs improvement" reason, and then pick one of the appropriate sub-reasons. For the case where the question contains images of code instead of text, you should choose the sub-reason that speaks of it lacking a "minimal, reproducible example".

Jeanne Dark already linked you to the canonical FAQ on why images of code are not acceptable: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You may want to post something like this in a comment to advise the asker, but it is not necessary (the flag is sufficient).

Regarding the downvotes: users are free to vote however they like on posts, whether up or down, as long as they are not engaging in vote fraud. So, I will not comment on the "appropriateness" of the downvotes in your case—or any other. There are many, many reasons why an answer might be downvoted. It might be wrong, or it might be unclear, or someone might think you should not have answered an inappropriate question, etc. You cannot know for certain exactly why someone has downvoted.

Therefore, the primary reason to avoid answering low-quality questions is not to avoid downvotes, but rather to spend your time in places where it will better contribute to our overall goal:

> [With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed, high-quality answers to every question about programming.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

There are many other practical reasons not to answer questions that should be closed, not the least of which is that any edit to the question to correct its issues might lead to invalidating your answer. That creates a mess for everyone. Another selfish reason is that the whole Q&A might get deleted if it is not edited to meet our minimum requirements, which would be effectively throwing away your efforts at writing an answer. Your efforts are better spent on better questions.

Comment: So, should I delete my answer?

Comment: That's up to you. You already wrote it, so it isn't doing any harm to leave it. In the future, though, I would recommend not taking the time to answer these questions until they are edited into shape. @justANewbie

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but from the link it is not clear to me which are the required *minimum standards* for a question, and which are additional features that make a question a *good* question.

Answer (score 7):

*Very* related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions) and [Is the How to Answer article's section on only answering well-asked questions advice or site policy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Also highly related: [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194963/should-one-downvote-answers-to-off-topic-questions)

Short answer: don't answer questions that don't meet site quality standards (which this question didn't for reasons that were already explained).

From a practical perspective, trying to answer these questions can be a very frustrating experience. Questions that are too broad, unclear, or lack details often take significantly more effort to understand and answer than well-formulated questions.

Also, with many of these questions, you don't even know if you're addressing the OP's real problem unless they edit the question to improve it. I remember a question where the OP wrote a question basically asking for the entire code base. I asked what they tried in the comments, and it turned out that they already had (mostly) working code; the main thing that they were missing was that they were expecting the `Math.Abs` function to edit an array in place (which it doesn't). So, in this case, if I had answered the question as originally formulated, I wouldn't have addressed the OP's real problem (which would've wasted both of our time and prevented the OP from learning that fact for future assignments).