# Is it acceptable to post answers generated by an AI, such as GitHub Copilot?

Tags: discussion, answers

Today, I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69772495/365237). In that answer, there is an explanation with the code:

> This code was written by Github Copilot with minimal supervision

and nothing else. I see some potential problems with this:

- user submitting such an answer might not be able to reason about the answer at all
- there is high rate of incorrectness with Copilot generated code ([source1](https://www.theregister.com/2021/08/25/github_copilot_study/), [source2](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/08/26/github-copilot-security.aspx))
- does the user even have the rights to submit such code into Stack Overflow

What do you think, is this ok? If not, what should be done about them?

Comment: Relevant consideration: [should one answer questions that do not meet our minimum standards?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412665/should-i-answer-questions-that-include-images-of-code-or-violate-other-guidelin)

Comment: I see users often posting only code code which doesn't quite answer the question. They seem to be unable to reason about it, either. Some times it's just copy-pasted, some times it's (presumably) an original work but not even related to the problem statement. I'm not sure if you consider these better or worse to automatically generated code which also happens to be wrong but I'd rank them the same, personally. Seems both are simply not useful.

Comment: @VLAZ they might or might not be useful, and certainly not very good answers. However, in this case we know the submitter does not actually create the content him/herself, so I think this case is worse by definition.

Comment: I don't think there is a requirement for the contributor to submit all original work. We are happy to accept an answer that points to a well-known solution that the posted didn't create themselves. We do require *proper attribution* for that, of course, but the point is that a post that contains non-original work is not, by itself, a problem.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However in this case I think there are additional, related problems. This is non-original work where the source is also not verifiable, since copilot does not really reveal its logic why it came about this specific answer, and even with copilot attribution we can't know how that answer was reached.

Comment: Disclaimer on all other answers: *The code was written by me being 100% sane and not intoxicated by drugs, alcohol or other substances.* ...

Comment: @rene *The comment was written by me being 100% high on technology*

Comment: It would be fun if StackOverflow would be part of CoPilot's training set, in which case answers generated through CoPilot would be some sort of reinforced learning ...

Comment: I think if co-pilot can answer a question it must be generic enough to be already asked in so.

Comment: "*This is non-original work where the source is also not verifiable, since copilot does not really reveal its logic why it came about this specific answer*" I still don't really see the difference between that and somebody posting "try this <code dump>". We still don't know how the author came to the decision for the code. And I have seen some *baffling* examples. I accept the attribution dispute being interesting poiint but I'm not sure I buy the concern about posting the code other than that. Either the poster will explain the code or not. Doesn't matter who authored it.

Comment: @VLAZ you should probably add it as an answer then :)

Comment: 'It would be fun if StackOverflow would be part of CoPilot's training set'...erk!  Kernel panic #FEEDFOOD...

Comment: @MartinJames - What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: When I read the answer this post is based upon I also had an thought of writing a meta question of my own.  The title would've been "Is Copilot a future of SO?". I envisioned Copilot (or similar AI) auto-answering questions. When I started answering questions on this side I quite often would find an approach on-line (possibly on SO itself) and then adopt it to OP's needs.  Not much different.

Comment: @VLAZ "...but I'd rank them the same, personally." I might be much easier to produce garbage content with the help of an automated system than without one. So maybe not a problem with average quality but one with quantity.

Comment: "user submitting such an answer might not be able to reason about the answer at all" Then the user was rather the copilot. Maybe we could cut out the middlemen completely. Just recognize such answers and attribute them to a copilot user account as long as attribution is given.

Comment: @Trilarion I don't see users struggling with producing garbage content without an AI to assist them. If an account produces a continued stream of content that the community doesn't find useful, then they get a ban on questions or answers.

Comment: This whole robo-flagging and robo-answering made me wonder, why do I still vote manually. Given all the thousands of my past votes, should an AI not be able to automatically determine what I like and what I do not like. Maybe a pretrained network on all the content with all the scores and then further trained on my votes which then votes for me if it's highly confident I would vote that way with the possibility for me to override should I not concur. That would surely save some time and I could train only on the content, not on score or name, in the spirit of SO.

Comment: @Trilarion Why stop there? You could make it anticipate what questions you'd like to ask as well. No more searching but not finding anything on SO - the asking and answering AIs have got you convered!

Comment: @Zoe You're right. My presence as content creator is hardly required anymore. One day an AI from an AI collective will post on AI meta complaining about downvotes without comments and will of course be downvoted into oblivion by its fellows and it will cry (an internal state will take a large negative value).

Comment: Over the ownership issue, I managed to come across this: [GitHubCopilot FAQs](https://copilot.github.com/#faq-do-i-need-to-credit-github-copilot-for-helping-me-write-code). So basically, the one who generated the code owns the code.

Comment: @Maaz that's what they claim, yes. However with cases like [this](https://twitter.com/Tercicatrix/status/1411075466094645252) it is doubtful if they can make that claim. This has now a separate question on [law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74137/who-owns-the-right-to-the-code-generated-by-github-copilot), and [fossa agrees](https://fossa.com/blog/analyzing-legal-implications-github-copilot/) that it's not easy to reason about.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at it all wrong. I was under the assumption that since they claimed something, it must be true, which isn't the case necessarily. How naive of me!

Comment: I don't know why no one is mentioning or taking into account this, but AI is just a name made for marketing...the closest thing would be Neural Network, but that's also not it either. I feel like [Statistical Learning](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such/191214#comment516040_191214) is a much better term for this. AI is in no way intelligent, even if you take into account the result (which is mostly random in most times instead of deterministic).

Comment: Related announcement by the mods: [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/1478931) (as of December 5, 2022).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In light of the GPT ban, I asked about this today here on Meta, but the question was closed as a duplicate of [Are all generative AIs banned?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422949/11810933).

Since Copilot is, as I understand it from the [OpenAI Codex](https://openai.com/blog/openai-codex) announcement a "descendant of GPT-3", content and output from it seem to be directly banned under the [current policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Regardless, since my "Does Github Copilot generated code fall under the GPT ban?" question was closed as a duplicate of [Are all generative AIs banned?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422949/11810933), it appears that the answer is what @RyanM posted there:

> ... it violates our rules on pasting AI-generated content without validating it. We can't verify exactly which AI system generated a piece of content, but we can often tell when someone is using one.
>
> ...
>
> This exemplifies exactly why we don't allow this sort of content: it's easy to let errors slip past, and the work required to catch them is time-consuming.

Answer (score 48):

Yes, posting an answer generated by an AI is acceptable, so long as the source is attributed. It's still a code-only answer (i.e. what the code does, or how it solves the problem is unexplained), which is not great, but the fact that it was generated by an AI doesn't really matter.

To address the concerns directly

> user submitting such an answer might not be able to reason about the answer at all

Sure, but that's irrelevant. Whether or not the user *understands* the answer they posted is not the concern of the site.

> there is high rate of incorrectness with Copilot generated code (source1, source2)

Again, not a problem. The quality of the answer should be judged on its own. It's similar to how an answer is judged in isolation, without considering whether the user has a history of posting incorrect answers.

> does the user even have the rights to submit such code into Stack Overflow

I *think* so. At least it's fine so long as the source is attributed, and there's no license on code generated by GitHub Copilot that prevents it being used on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The last point sounds sketchy to me: As long as there is no license *allowing* redistribution (and perhaps derivative works) of the generated code, it seems like a copyright issue. I tried to find out whether github copilot offers any license to the generated code but 5mins of googling yielded no good results. Especially there is also the issue that posting it on SO is *relicensing*

Comment: @lucidbrot: GitHub asserts that Copilot's use of source code doesn't infringe copyright, so I'd think that by that logic one can use the outputs without restriction too. (although this depends on GH's controversial assertion about copyright on training data being correct)

Comment: Also, OpenAI (which actually owns the model) [says](https://beta.openai.com/policies/terms-of-use) "OpenAI will not assert copyright over Content generated by the API for you or your end users"

Comment: @Smitop [I beg to differ](https://twitter.com/Tercicatrix/status/1411075466094645252)

Comment: @lucidbrot I'm afraid I don't know what the policy is for using that code. It shouldn't matter from SO's end anyway, since 3rd party policies are not enforced here.

Comment: How do you even attribute the source when the source is unknown? Do you just attribute the AI? Isn't that like attributing the plagiarist?

Comment: @CodyGray I don't follow. If the code was generated by some AI tool, then that's the source that needs to be attributed, right? What does it matter where the tool got the code from? That's the tool's problem I would think. For example, if I were to use some code that's posted on SO, I just need to attribute SO. Am I expected to track down where the user who posted the code got it from?

Comment: Copilot does not attribute the sources the training data comes from, does it? Should be no problem for an AI to provide the bill of material for the output but somehow it is not part of the package AFAIK.

Comment: I can't edit... but to quote [the GitHub Copilot website](https://copilot.github.com/#faq-who-owns-the-code-github-copilot-helps-me-write): "**Who owns the code GitHub Copilot helps me write?** ... The suggestions GitHub Copilot generates, and the code you write with its help, belong to you, and you are responsible for it**". IANAL, but my interpretation of that is that you own the code it writes

Comment: A translation is still a translation even if automated. They may own the database work (of code they have in their deep learning or machine learning database), but don't have the copyright for the original works which normally require attribution if it's open source.

Comment: @hakre, even if the ML model was trained on copyrighted data that doesn't automatically mean that its output is also copyrighted, same as when a human artist looks at another's painting and draws an original work inspired by it. There are situations when Copilot recites its training data, but [they are extremely rare in practice](https://docs.github.com/en/github/copilot/research-recitation#results).

Comment: Sure, I always say that when I re-encode a youtube video or two, only the process was trained / seeded with copyrighted data, it's not that the output is, this is the endless summer! Look, I only looked at that video and than made a program paint a new one!

Comment: @cocomac: You don't need to be a lawyer to read that sentence: _"helps me write"_ - the code is written by _"[you/]me"_ - copilot does only _"help"_ and further on: _"the suggestions [the program] generates"_ and again _"the code you write with its help"_ - the author only gets help or suggestions, the write is only the own code, if it's written on their own, not about taking the suggestions verbatim. So that statement tells nothing about using the AI to auto-fill an answer on SO for example. And so it's not about the code "it writes", but first of all about the code you/me _writes_.

Comment: @hakre, you want to argue ad absurdum? Ok, have you ever read copyrighted code?  If yes, then, do you claim that anything you write now is violating the copyright?

Comment: @Aivean: It's simple to over-exaggerate, but there is reason for clean room implementations as well. And yes, if I translate or transpose copyrighted works I respect its authors demands and conform with the licensing when I publish. And for proprietary/reciprocal works, I first of all pay to use and read. Only you/me make use of copyrighted code - and the use includes own writing - is not automatically violating copyright, you see?

Comment: @hakre, we are getting into the legal waters here. As I posted in my answer here, there is no legal precedent yet about whether neural network output is infringing on the training data. I believe that it's a clear example [of fair use](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/fair-use-what-transformative.html), but I understand if you disagree, it's a complicated legal question.

Comment: @Aivean: I think the compiling of source code into a binary form is pretty well understood. And software as work is covered and has legal precedent. The question is if we can see a new quality here. From user comments, no, that suggestion machine is not offering a new quality level. More on the level of a search engine as you said it well. Specialized on code, sure, Microsofts didn't spend billions to get hands on it just for nothing, so it's required to turn it over into something different, and Copilot may look promising as a tool to do that with millions of users.

Comment: (1) As a non-mod, I can't move this to chat, but it seems to make more sense there (2) As to the question regarding copyright of GitHub Copilot created code, I've made a [Law SE question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74137/who-owns-the-right-to-the-code-generated-by-github-copilot) in hopes of getting a better answer, hopefully, one backed by evidence

Comment: “*The quality of the answer should be judged on its own.*” I think that is missing an important point. Every human user should have the benefit of doubt, as they might produce a useful answer some day. But there is no reason to allow an AI that is incapable of producing useful answers in general, as it can’t explain its copied code snippets (so it can only produce low-quality code-only answers) and require our moderators to clean up after that AI. It’s not as if there wasn’t already enough work for them without such AIs.

Comment: @Holger, *"AI that is incapable of producing useful answers in general, as it can’t explain its copied code snippets"* — that statement is not true. Copilot is capable of explaining code in plain English, perhaps even better, than the average human (especially non-native speaker). Sure, it makes mistakes, more often for complex tasks, but so do humans. And that's why human supervision is required for now. But Copliot (or other language models) will improve in the future, it's inevitable.

Comment: GitHub copilot is a remarkable way of circumventing copyleft open-source licenses. It hoovers up all kinds of source code in public repos, then grinds up the ideas in them, then spits out anonymized versions of the formerly copylefted code. Still, maybe StackOverflow could license their cut/paste keyboard to github :-). At any rate, don't cut and paste code from anywhere without understanding it thoroughly. It's just sloppy and rude to your users.

Comment: @Aivean there’s a fundamental difference between assembling and reformatting English text and *explaining* something. Explaining requires understanding. Including the ability to respond to comments pointing out mistakes, asking for clarifications, or suggesting improvements.

Answer (score 26):

I am the author of that "Copilot answer", and I'd like to give my thoughts on the matter.

First of all, I admit that my answer was subpar, as it didn't provide any explanation besides the code itself and can be perceived as just a mindless copy-paste, and the disclaimer about "minimal supervision" didn't help the matter. I tried to rectify that by editing the answer.

That being said, I believe it is not relevant to the question of whether Copilot can be used to answer SO questions in general.

Copilot is a tool. I think, that for all intents and purposes of Stack Overflow answers, it's no different from using Google or code completion in IDEs. The only potential issue is the legality of its output.

On that, there is no definite answer yet (as in there is no established legal precedent; probably a good question for [law.stackexchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)). And I don't think there can be a simple answer either. It probably would differ on a case-by-case basis (see [Google v Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_LLC_v._Oracle_America,_Inc.) case), but the point is open to debate.

Copilot and natural language neural nets in general work similar to humans in the sense that they memorize parts of their training data and then recombine them to achieve the given goal. See [this article](https://docs.github.com/en/github/copilot/research-recitation#results) to get a sense of how original the Copilot output is (one recitation event every 10 user weeks).

Currently, there are no restrictions on the usage of Copilot output from GitHub and Microsoft, so I think the legal responsibility to avoid copyright infringement falls on the user. Note, this is pretty much the same as with any user-posted code. You don't know how that code was produced and whether it infringes some copyright. You just trust the user by default. Controversially, with Copilot you can probably be **more** confident that the code is original.

---

To summarise, I think that using Copilot to produce parts or the whole of the Stack Overflow answer is no different from using Google. You are still responsible for your answer, in terms of quality, relevance, and legality.  The usage (from the legal standpoint) of the Copilot output for any purposes is not restricted at this point.

---

**Update:** Since there are lots of questions regarding how exactly the original answer was produced, I recorded [a short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-piLQpbAoI), which illustrates the whole process.

Comment: Your answer here makes sense but it seems to me that it misrepresents your answer being debated. I agree that Copilot is just a tool. Using a tool doesn't inherently make a post bad. Similarly to how one can still ask good questions based on homework. But when the problematic feature becomes a defining property of the question (homework dump, Copilot dump) that's a problem. The key is human supervision. As you know even a lot of humans write terrible and harmful code, and a neural net trained on crap will generate crap.

Comment: So when you say "*This code was written by Github Copilot with minimal supervision*" instead of "I also used Copilot for this answer", you are suggesting that there was no human supervision. Instead of "a tool like Google or code completion in IDEs" you make the tool the author. Tools can't reason about code correctness and code quality. When you give a chimpanzee a keyboard and let it write code at least it's obvious that the result is probably useless. Copilot can write convincing garbage. You can only use it as a tool, but then the fact that you used it becomes irrelevant for the answer.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, I already said that my answer was low quality, including the wording of the disclaimer, but that was for reasons unrelated to Copilot usage. I think this is a trivial matter and is not worth discussing. I agree with you on the topic of supervision, and I believe I've stated so in this post.

Comment: A question of personal interest about the code example you provided with your answer: Did you take the code verbatim? As you wrote in the disclaimer (thanks for placing it there), that the code has been generated by a program and was not written by yourself. Or as you wrote here in your answer - exemplary - that you provided input to that program to "google" for a search result (with the only difference perhaps that google leaves a link to the original sources with the search results while that program is a bit more opaque regarding the source of the results)?

Comment: @Andras Deak: A tool can never be an author, that's not how it (computes) nor an author works. And the author did place the answer there, which requires - at least - a minimum of supervision. Even if it's only to place the cursor and then select start to end , copy and paste into a place that the answer matches with its syntax - I have not read about any complaints on the formatting for example. And then even a disclaimer has been written, which clearly shows that supervision took place, not only a minimal one. And on SO the asking person has to say whether the answer was helpful or not.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I'm sure the neural network is not static and has been designed, maintained and run/feed by humans. There are certainly a plenty of authors, but for the tool it's just working like a machine. The direct commandment of that machine is by the author of the answer (at least most upfront). Yes, it's sometimes hard to not question an asking persons intention on SO, but I think it's correct to not do it. And similarly, I would then also handle it the same for an answering persons motivation.

Comment: @hakre, full disclosure, the question was so trivial that I decided to use it as a test for Copilot. I prompted it with a comment, something like `//remove the last word from a string`.  Again, the generated one-liner function was trivial. Even so, I found it doesn't handle the "string without spaces" case, so I added it. The disclaimer that I wrote was more to inform people about the existence and abilities of Copilot, not because I thought it's necessary to attribute it.

Comment: @Avean: I was also able to see the now deleted answer and it is far more than just the output of Microsofts code suggestion engine. It perhaps got deleted because of being placed on meta (sometimes called the "meta-effect" as it creates attention). I'm sure if you would have skipped the disclaimer (the one I commented on earlier and think its great you did nevertheless) it would have never got that attention. Also you being responsive here I think is great. Thanks for your contributions. I find this highly interesting.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, *"If the code block was belched up by a neural network and pasted into an answer verbatim, it was authored by the neural network."* no, [not legally](https://definitions.uslegal.com/a/author-copyright/).

Comment: @hakre 1) at the time I created this question, the answer was just the output of the AI generation. it was expanded later on. 2) do also note that the entire question was deleted which results in answers being deleted too, so this answer in particular was not the target of a deletion.

Comment: @eis: OK, but according to your question here on meta, it was with the notice that the code was generated, right?

Comment: "You don't know how that code was produced..." I think that's the crucial point. Readers of the answer may be able to better judge the quality of the content if they know how the code was produced. On the other hand, it could also lead to prejudice. I would prefer is automatically generated code is marked as such, but I mostly worry about subpar code quality of automatically generated code (we might not yet there, where AI can take over (or maybe we are)).

Comment: "*it's no different from using Google or code completion in IDEs*" I mean you have to start writing code yourself for IDEs to offer code completion, and you get to determine whether you agree or want to ignore it. That doesn't seem to be present in Copilot. "Just like google" is also an enormous stretch. The biggest thing missing from both is the human discernment factor, which should *not* be understated.

Comment: "*The only potential issue is the legality of its output. On that, there is no definite answer yet*" Huh? The legality of its output should be considered the same as the legality of any other output, which does have a definite answer: don't violate users' copyrights. If Copilot takes code from somewhere that it doesn't have the license to use... you've violated copyright and broken Stack Overflow's rules. If Copilot takes code from somewhere and you don't *know* who wrote it or what license to provide under it, you can't possibly license it/attribute it acceptably for use on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Personally I don't see how anyone can rely on Copilot-generated code without having access to the full body of training data GitHub arguably stole for its use, to know which bits are verbatim copied and need to be licensed appropriately (if the licenses even permit it). They have made some noise about some small percentage being 100% identical to existing code, but it only takes 1 function, 1 comment, 1 license fragment to make it exceedingly clear that that output is, well, stolen code.

Comment: @hakre yes. just the output of the AI generation and the part I quoted. you can still see it in revision history.

Comment: @eis: yeah true, I could have just looked in the edits, my fault. sorry to bother you with that.

Comment: @TylerH, please check [the video that I linked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-piLQpbAoI), hope it will help you understand how Copilot works better. Regarding the "arguably stole" part. Are you familiar with the term "fair use"? There is a good reason to believe that Copilot output is [transformative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformative_use), and cherry-picked exceptions are just that.

Comment: @Aivean I am quite familiar with the term fair use, but *copying verbatim* is not fair use. A work doesn't qualify for fair use just by *being* transformative... being transformative is a requirement in *addition* to one of the fair use exceptions.

Comment: @TylerH, why do you think that Copilot's output is "copying verbatim"? It can be, accidentally (with low probability), or if explicitly prompted (Q_rsqrt), but that's not the issue in the general case. Don't let the overhyped examples on the internet mislead you.

Comment: @Aivean Well, it has to copy it verbatim, first, in order to train on it. Second, maybe you didn't see the Tweet that Zoe linked under the question above: https://twitter.com/Tercicatrix/status/1411075466094645252 I'm sure this is not an isolated case, just a glaringly obvious one because of the content that it wrote.

Comment: @TylerH, *"it has to copy it verbatim, first, in order to train on it"*: copying the code openly hosted on github for the purposes of indexing it is a textbook example of fair use, and listed in GH terms of service. RE: *"the Tweet that Zoe linked"*, I literally mentioned "Q_rsqrt" in my previous comment. In my opinion it's one of the few overhyped cherry-picked examples on the internet that discredit the Copilot's image.

Comment: Thanks for the video! Can you expand the video's description? When there isn't audio or overlay text in the video itself, it is especially important that the video's description provides some context. For instance, what is the purpose of the video? What is going on in the video? - I presume you write some prose and then Copilot generates code, but I am not sure. What are the main steps in the video (its structure)? What is the conclusion at the end of video? - e.g. what are we supposed to have learned after having seen it? What are some references for further reading or viewing (YouTube)?

Comment: The video's title ought to be corrected to *"How to write [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance)* ***answers*** *using [GitHub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) Copilot"* (three changes). (Or *"How to write* ***a*** *Stack Overflow answer using* ***GitHub*** *Copilot"*). You can edit both the title and description of the video (though it may not be immediately obviously where and how).

Comment: @PeterMortensen, thank you for the suggestions, I've implemented some of them. I added a brief description to the video, but I don't think that I need to explain every little detail. I assume that viewers interested in the topic already have some relevant background and can infer what is going on. If not, there is a comment section there.

Comment: @TylerH "...that output is, well, stolen code." This reminds me a bit on that other question about taking content from GitHub. There people said that posting on SO is no problem because whatever it is, it's fair use anyway. Here, unless the CoPilot literally breaks in and steals code that would otherwise be private, if the copilot examples used are public than using the results on SO should also be fair use (transformed in between but that doesn't change the status) or not?

Comment: @Trilarion Posting on SO in a genuine manner is typically (arguably, no actual legal precedent yet) fair use by design, but the *crux* of the issue here is whether an AI-written code (in some cases, verbatim, not transformative) qualifies for that. "It's posted on Stack Overflow" is not mentioned as an explicit fair use carve-out in 17 U.S. Code § 107, unfortunately. The problem is that we don't know and can't predict whether code "generated" by Copilot is actually novel or just a verbatim copy of some other code, *or* what license that code was under. That's what I mean by "stolen".

Comment: @Trilarion It's the same issue raised by Cody elsewhere here (I think, maybe another thread). If someone plagiarizes code that can't legally be copied, and you copy that plagiarized code and give attribution to the plagiarizer, that's... not really a good situation. You may not necessarily *know* that the code you cited was illegally obtained and published, but that doesn't excuse the citation's infraction on the same issue. What is Copilot's full corpus of work? Where is it listed? Is there a guarantee that it only scans code that itself is guaranteed published under open licenses?

Answer (score 20):

> does the user even have the rights to submit such code into Stack Overflow

This I cannot answer, as I am unfamiliar with what rules and agreements there are to Copilot. However, it probably is the biggest point to discuss here - the other concerns you've raised seem like a red herring:

> - user submitting such an answer might not be able to reason about the answer at all
> - there is high rate of incorrectness with Copilot generated code (source1, source2)

We get many users submitting an answer they have not authored themselves. That act, by itself, is not an issue. Users are allowed to refer to other solutions ([with proper attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/)) and not all work has to be completely original. This includes mentioning well-known algorithms, or even using their implementations. It is part of an age old tradition of [standing on the shoulders of giants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_on_the_shoulders_of_giants).

With that said, whether or not a user can reason about an existing solution has a bit more relevance. We do not *require* this, but it often makes for a poor answer if the content amounts to "use this" without explaining how or why. It is indeed possible that a user who cannot reason about a solution misapplies it to a problem.

In a very similar way, an automatically generated solution can be not useful or misapplied. So, there is very little difference whether it was produced by a live person or an automated system. In the end, the result is the same: we should rate *content*. And content that is not useful should be downvoted. Exceptionally poor answers may even be deleted.

Note that if it happens that content *is* useful then the appropriate action would be to upvote it. Does not matter if it was automatically generated or not. Same with any other answer posted by a user.

If we ever get some sort of automated system that leaves helpful and useful answers, then please refer to the final panel of this comic:

[image: XKCD #810]

Comment: In hopes of getting the `does the user even have the rights to submit such code into Stack Overflow` question answered, I've asked a (slightly more general) [question regarding rights to the code produced by GitHub Copilot](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/74137/41492) on Law SE

Answer (score 8):

I'm worried about two things here: quality and false pretenses. It doesn't mean they necessarily have to be a problem, but here they are:

**More low quality content?**

Are algorithms and large amounts of data already good enough to provide good enough quality to satisfyingly answer programming questions with little to no supervision? Together with the simplicity of generating large amount of content via automated means, this could lead to a surge in low quality content.

Related is that in the comments here people do not seem to have a problem with the content creator not necessarily having to understand what he/she posts and how that works. This doesn't sound like a recipe for high quality to me. At least the content creator should have understood the content. If automatically generated content really is just a tool and carefully checked and tested and understood, I'd say it's okay, but it rather seems we would be happy with fully automated user accounts. The quality of these may vary.

**Who actually creates that content?**

To me it's a contract that the user name that is printed below a content contribution has a significant impact on the content and not just for example: started a program. Obviously it might be a bit of a grey zone how much a significant contribution to created content really is, but if we seem to be okay with more of less fully automated created content (where the user account is the copilot or maybe only the name giver) then I think putting a user name below that content could be seen as a kind of false pretense and it would be better to print something else there.

**Conclusion**

Quality is usually dealt with by voting and automatically generated content could additionally be attributed as suggested in another answer. Both might be fully satisfiable. Time will tell.

Comment: "[...] people do not seem to have a problem with the content creator not necessarily having to understand what he/she posts and how that works." Strictly speaking, this is how it works currently; content creator on Stack Overflow absolutely do not have to understand either question or answer to post content. I mean, system-wise. Obviously we humans would like to think they *do*.

Comment: "*Related is that in the comments here people do not seem to have a problem with the content creator not necessarily having to understand what he/she posts and how that works*" I "do not have a problem" with this in that we've had this over the past decade. [This joke was posted in 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) - 12 years ago. It's making fun of a trend that is no less of human not understanding posts than an AI doing the same. I don't know how we enforce posters understand the question and the answer they post. It literally shows up daily. Me "not having a problem" is because

Comment: I don't see it as a *separate* problem to solve than humans posting answers they don't understand or responding to questions they don't understand. Again, this already happens. If you want to address this - *great* I'd love to see less low quality submissions. I just don't see how we'd enforce it. And in the spirit of being fair to everybody we shouldn't stop it *right now*. Since AI answers fall in the same problem category, I don't see why we should do anything special to handle them instead of addressing the broader trend of low quality posts.

Comment: @VLAZ I see your point. But I argue more about what should be "people should actually understand the content they post in answers" and more quantitatively. If an AI is even worse than the average human here, then quality will go down on average and that's what I would like to avoid, even though there might be some humans even less capable than an AI. You could convince me that an AI is doing great work by showing me a large enough number of examples of answers written by an AI. That would surely reduce my first concern. But that hasn't been done so far.

Comment: "*You could convince me that an AI is doing great work by showing me a large enough number of examples of answers written by an AI.*" I am myself not convinced we humans are doing great work.

Comment: @VLAZ Sure, so maybe we could check and verify the output of both, humans and AI. Nothing against it. But without I'd rather say that AIs are still very dumb and I would prefer the content produced by a human expert any day. For many of the questions on SO, when they aren't actually duplicates, you would probably require a bit of creativity to solve them. Maybe AI should first do the job of detecting duplicates. Might also be an easier task.

Comment: "*Maybe AI should first do the job of detecting duplicates. Might also be an easier task.*" [paper published on this topic](http://papers.www2017.com.au.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/proceedings/p1221.pdf) and [another one](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8964380). I don't have the knowledge to evaluate these but just wanted to show there has been some work on this. [There are also some community solutions listed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343395).

Comment: @VLAZ Many thanks for the references. What will probably happen in the future is that somebody conducts similar studies with AI written answers.

Answer (score -8):

Stack Overflow is an invaluable resource for many professionals, as well as AI researchers. The process adopted by the site combined with the volume of traffic and collaborators is what produces its awesome value. At the start, Stack Overflow was an innovation, and I think the spirit of the site from the beginning was to collaborate in our different fields to create a significant volume of knowledge. I don't think the particular process of collaboration was as critical as the end result. So long as the people behave well and get value out of the Stack Overflow platform, it should succeed. And clearly it did succeed :). Not to minimize the great execution of the Stack Overflow team.

As AI evolves there may be a day when it will be able to answer every question here. And we should be very happy about it if it comes to pass. In the meantime there will be many stumbles along the way. And I can see a very important role for Stack Overflow to play, to create that future, by allowing this platform to be another point of collaboration with that future AI. I think AI answers are not just acceptable, but should be encouraged. By design, Stack Overflow supervises all activity on the platform including, of course, AI generated answers.  The only caveat could be, to not post so many answers such that Stack Overflow overflows, since Stack Overflow is still managed by humans.

I think it would be very useful to have an AI generated answer flag, to help with managing the process.

It is a very exciting time indeed!!!

Comment: Regarding "*I think it would be very useful to have an AI generated answer flag*", say hi to [natty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6817005/natty) :) And that's not the only bot that raises flags on SO. There's a whole [fleet](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347) of them.