# How do you plan on tackling ChatGPT answers?

Tags: discussion, cheating

I've came back to Stack Overflow (after a while) to test out [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT).

The [OpenAI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenAI) community has built something insane. I literally copy and pasted the SO input questions to the platform input and it gave me the result in less than 2 seconds with extremely proficient explanation (code + code explanation).

The craziest thing was that no moderator noticed anything suspicious when providing the answers, at least not yet. What is Stack Overflow's plan about this?

ChatGPT is for sure a disrupting technology. What are your thoughts?
You can check my answers (oldest: 74649101, youngest: 74659987) on stackoverflow.com; all were given by OpenAI ChatGPT.

Is this even legal? Any thoughts are welcome. I suspect a lot of people will start doing the same if not already. Are there any mechanism by which SO can recognise such things?

Check my profile for ChatGPT answers https://stackoverflow.com/users/2951933/eugensunic?tab=answers

Comment: Does it check for duplicates? If so, I'm all over it. If not, I want it dead ;-).

Comment: At the scale of Stack Overflow ~2 hours is a _very_ short amount of time for things to be "noticed". We did have a similar discussion a bit ago: [Is it acceptable to post answers generated by an AI, such as GitHub Copilot?](/q/412696/15497888) I'm not sure what (if any) salient differences there are between chatGPT and Copilot.

Comment: This is much different, please give it a try, it gives a good explanation and if not satisfied you could ask for more explanation etc.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal?  No one has yet to prove all of my answers aren't generated from a robot.  They're either voted up or down and accepted or not based on their content, not their source.

Comment: You *really* need to verify that those answers actually do what they're supposed to do before posting them. Eg, https://stackoverflow.com/a/74649919/4014959 needs to use `continue`, not `break`.

Comment: I've got 50 points in 2.5 hours with just copy pasting, that says something...

Comment: _"Is this legal?"_ - what license is the content created by the AI released to you under? Does it give you the right to re-license it to SO under CC BY-SA per [the TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)? Given that you're not actually writing it there's also the issue of attribution; you're _quoting_, not creating.

Comment: You will just end up creating a load of code only answers that might indeed bring you direct reputation points but will only answer the OPs issue, leading to no reputation in a long run. On top of that, those answers not aligned with the goal of our Q&A. While good answers do explain the code and important principles, they can be reused in the future and in for other users. You'll soon realise that those good answers will bring you reputation in the long run _"without breaking a sweat"_, as you said yourself.

Comment: The fact that AI can answer these questions so readily comes across to me as a sign that they are not very good questions.

Comment: I'm amazed how you guys aren't worried a bit...

Comment: And what would "being worried" change? You already said you keep doing that since it generates points for you.

Comment: Also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74656615/3001761

Comment: “I'm amazed how you guys aren't worried a bit...” - I am more worried you are submitting low quality code only answers and nobody is calling you out on the lack of quality (yet).

Comment: I've gained now +111 points just by asking chatGPT questions, and breaking no sweat, that tells everything.. I'm also worried about moderators ant their activity on this site...

Comment: @jonrsharpe Technically works of art created by ML are in the public domain, as a computer cannot be assigned a copyright.

Comment: @SecurityHound They aren't code-only answers, though. Some of them have quite a lot of non-code text.

Comment: *"I'm also worried ..."* ...  is this a poor trolling attempt? It is obvious that you don't care. You wouldn't continue when were actually worried.

Comment: I noticed this answer/account and came looking to see if this was already addressed on meta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74667553/generate-a-card-with-random-images/74667580#74667580

Comment: Posting answers you cannot verify as correct is antisocial and actively harmful, whether they were generated by AI, sent to you by a friend, or scrawled backwards on your bathroom mirror by an unseen presence.  If your point is that this is a problem and we should worry about it, doing it yourself is not an acceptable way to make the point. If someone mugged you, you wouldn't thank them for pointing out how easy it is to mug someone, would you?  Please stop doing this. Anyone else who is doing this: please stop.

Comment: @jcalz I earned hard my reputation during my college years. My intention is not to ruin this community and face unnecessary ramifications. Just wanted to try this out and was amazed how easy it was to earn 100+ reps without breaking a sweat.

Comment: If you don't want to face "unnecessary ramifications" you could delete any of your answers which you cannot personally verify as being correct, or at least any of the answers with which people have explicitly pointed out problems.

Comment: Re *"...last 10 answers"*: That quickly becomes out of date (at least partially). Is the youngest one ID 74659745? Or ID 74654402 (the *current* last two answers were a separation of hours)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I've deleted the downvoted answers. I'm think I'm good now.
Please check my EDIT (oldest to youngest IDs included)

Comment: @cigien it doesn't

Comment: Could you clarify why you feel the linked post doesn't answer your question? If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're asking "I'm posting answers using some AI like technology. What are the community's feelings about this?". That's exactly what the suggested duplicate is asking, only for a different (though very related) technology.

Comment: @cigien you explained it well, "for a different (though very related) technology". I would just like to add that it's a much more different technology.

Comment: No, it's not a much more different technology. It's just the latest version of a technology that seems impressive to us because it's "human-like" (something which we, and I include myself, find very cool). However, the technology will continue to improve and there will be a new tool out in a couple of weeks/months/years that will be even cooler. I don't see that we need a new Meta post about each one because I don't see that community consensus on how to deal with content generated by such tools is going to change each time.

Comment: @cigien - I can totally see community consensus changing as the tech evolves. Likely any problems caused by this tech will also change. For example as the tech becomes more viable for more questions and more "human like" in its responses I can imagine a greater proportion of FGITW answers that are not just "code only" and that are at least superficially plausible and that the humans on the site will need to spend longer evaluating and moderating these.

Comment: Also on Meta SE: [Could ChatGPT be a viable way to answer people's questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384355/241919)

Comment: One difference between   https://stackoverflow.com/a/74659987/3648282 and the duplicate (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412696/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-generated-by-an-ai-such-as-github-copilot) is that the duplicate is attributed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071/282094

Comment: "_chatGPT is for sure a disrupting technology. What are your thoughts?_" ever heard of ["garbage in, garbage out"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)? (that was a rhetorical question). This is like the "oh no- computers are learning to code and now they're going to take our jobs- oh wait- for the computer to solve a client's problem, the client will have to accurately describe what they want". Maybe go try to build something to detect unanswerable questions and ask the asker to clarify on what needs clarifying. I mean- what is ChatGPT going to do for "can you help me?" Qs?

Comment: If we can persuade the askers of obvious duplicates to go to chatgpt instead then the FGITW problem is solved ...

Comment: ["_Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541) (date: 2022-12-04).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The trouble with having an AI provide answers is what happens if you get comments on those answers?

If the comment says simply "this answer is wrong" how are you going to check the answer or correct it?

If the comment asks you to "please further explain the answer", are you equipped to do that?

If your AI can respond to additional questions and update the answer for you then it's effectively able to pass the Turing test in this limited problem domain, if not then your answers run the risk of simply being noise.

We can actually see that happen with your answers...

- [Comparing values from two arrays and creating objects accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74647566/comparing-values-from-two-arrays-and-creating-objects-accordingly/74649991#74649991)

  > This result doesn't seem to be the same sort of result the OP is looking for; you are generating a transaction for every possible sender/receiver pair, but it looks every transaction should "use up" either the sender or the receiver. So instead of s×r transactions there should be at most s+r-1.
- [Ignore duplicate array item code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649812/ignore-duplicate-array-item-code-not-working/74649919#74649919)

  > Would breaking out of the for loops at the first duplicate name cause it to miss names? There will likely be more non duplicate names past the duplicate in later iterations that that this would cause it to miss.
- [Using `.includes` on HTML Element Attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649707/using-includes-on-html-element-attributes/74649745#74649745)

  > nice! However, i'd like to avoid disassembling and reassembling the objects, if possible. This article seems to suggest a method. [masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/filter-array-of-objects](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/filter-array-of-objects)
- [.click() on document.getElementsByClassName()[i] does not click button in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649671/click-on-document-getelementsbyclassnamei-does-not-click-button-in-chrome/74649709#74649709)

  > Unfortunately I tried innerHtml and also using if(button as HTMLElement).offsetParent !== null && !(button as HTMLSelectElement).disabled) but no change to the results :/

How are you going to respond to these comments?

Or if the answer is downvoted...

- [React JS read file from storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74649791/react-js-read-file-from-storage/74649848#74649848)

  Do you understand whether there's something wrong with this answer and if so, how to correct it?

#### If you want to know what we're going to do about it, [see this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). I.e. using chatGPT to generate answers is currently banned.

Comment: I was able to make 51 points in a 2.5 hours frame, without breaking a sweat. I fed the AI with OPs additional comments and it did very well. I'll continue doing what I started, just to see how it performs. I still think this will be a big issue for SO

Comment: Is the above comment AI generated? It doesn't address the answer's point here at all, @EugenSunic

Comment: then the answers get downvoted, no problemo

Comment: @Rainb: When the problems are subtle and the answer *looks* well-written, "no problemo" is far from accurate.  Many readers will skim and upvote an answer that looks good, looks like it makes sense, because we're used to answers that look like that having been written by humans that also get the small details right.  When it looks good but requires careful examination to see that it isn't, it's a lot more likely to attract undeserved upvotes and displace actually correct answers.  Wasting time for curators, and for people who actually try to use code from such an answer.

Comment: You not only brag about violating the ban, you promise to continue?  SMH

Answer (score -37):

I've been doing this exact thing today, got +120 points of reputation, and even helped a few people.

I believe this is inevitable. If a bot can answer a question no worse than a human, then there's nothing Stack Overflow or anyone can do (it's all just text, not even an image!). Even if there were some kind of detection system, people would just correct the bot's output and give that text instead. Maybe Stack Overflow would incorporate its own version of the near future bot, which would answer people automatically even before they get to post for the people to see.

It's just the new reality, whether we are ready for it or not. The Internet will adapt, and a new era shall be born. Maybe we'll get to realize that we do not need jobs anymore to function as a society; we simply need electricity and robots to do all the work for us. If there aren't any jobs, the consumer doesn't have any money, and if they don't have any money to consume then the monetary system is impossible.

We need to be ready to transition into a new world, to realize that we can build an actual paradise and we do not need to suffer anymore of the monetary problems we suffered for centuries. There will be no poverty, no war, no greed, because there will no longer be scarcity, and no longer will money have value that caused the idea that we have scarcity on this planet. A new world would be abundant! A true mechanical paradise the world has never seen before!

Ehem, anyway, I had fun answering questions I barely have read or understood today :)

Comment: Could you please stop doing this unless you can verify whether or not the generated answer is correct?  Right now you're just making extra work for others who have to wade through answers which look okay at first glance but are quite often incorrect and sometimes complete nonsense.  That's antisocial; you should stop.

Comment: yeah ChatGPT themselves do state as a limitation "ChatGPT sometimes writes plausible-sounding but incorrect or nonsensical answers" and "plausible-sounding" may well be enough to garner some upvotes

Comment: First of all, my initial experiment was to see how easily I can submit an answer and get free reputation points. I was purposefully searching for dumb/simple question that can easily disprove any AI wrongness (which already happened a few times). Proven possible and not always accurate I've lost interest. Now what I do is tell the AI to write an answer based on what I actually intend to say. Secondly, I do check for obvious wrong answers now given by the prompt and I do check if the code works, it's not hard. You think telling me to stop it will stop EVERYONE from doing these silly stuff?

Comment: That's why we have multiple people checking for the answer and downvoting it. Telling me to not or what to do would do absolutely nothing. More AI programs coming, you cannot stop kids from doing exactly what I did can you? The best thing StackOverflow can do is to incorporate their own version of the AI so that it gives an AI answer the questions before they are submitted (the person will know that such thing exist and it can lower the number of duplicated/silly questions as well).

Comment: Re *"robots to do all the work for us"*: That was also predicted in the 1980s (the so-called "[leisure society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-work_society)"). It didn't happen.

Comment: "It didn't happen". A person been smoking for 20 years, says: "they said ill get cancer, yet I didn't!". Things take time y'know, your answer doesn't make any sense, because a lot of jobs are ALREADY being automated. Automation is a process, not an instant thing that happens on Tuesday morning.

Comment: @PeterMortensen considering the mathematics, programming, science you've done in your career you should leave the gates open for AI. Comparing 1980 to 2020+ is something I wouldn't expect from a guy like you. I agree with Jefferson, perhaps 100s of posters are deploying this technology to build a good SO cv.

Comment: Regarding "plausible sounding" in this case the answer seems so close - except it seems to have just invented a possible return code of `3` that isn't correct - or would even be relevant as return codes `1` and `2` are all that are needed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74668146/73226

Comment: -1 for  "answering questions I barely have read or understood today" That is truly terrible.

Comment: That was the whole point Vladimir

Comment: @Jefferson - The fact your low-quality plagiarized answer(s) were upvoted proves, more upvotes are as dangerous as downvotes and downvotes are as important as upvotes, all you have proven is you submitted numerous answers which you had no business submitting.

Comment: REALLY disappointed at people not only violating policy, but bragging about it.