# Many answers were given in a short period

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, new-users

I just left a comment beneath an answer by [a new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20681090/dom). The answer was wrong in several aspects. I visited their profile and was amazed at seeing they gave a staggering number of answers in a short period: 21 answers in 95 minutes.
Is this record-breaking? Does the (answering) system not need some defense against this as I'm sure many of these answers will be low-quality? Is there an answer-ban like there is a question-ban?

Comment: Maybe some bot? The answers are over several different areas, I see at least C++, C#, Java, R, Haskel, assembler. Though it is possible that the user has expertise in all these areas, I highly doubt it.

Comment: Looks like chatgpt again. It's an incredibly cool system, but it's sad to see people use it this way

Comment: Yeah, definitely chatgpt. "It sounds like you're trying to <blank>" is basically its signature to show what it understands the question as prior to giving an answer. In this case, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412696/6296561, which this user is in violation of

Comment: I apologize for polluting the community, but I wanted to see how long it would take for me to get my answers flagged or removed by moderators. I made no attempt to revise the answers that were provided by ChatGPT. It must be realized that there are ways to modify the pattern of its language so that it passes off as more human and avoids using specific phrases that are known to be generated by ChatGPT. 

Although I did generate a number of inaccurate posts, there were a good number that were accurate. Maybe these ought to be preserved, but have the author removed and my points removed.

Comment: @Dom we have our hands full dealing with regular crap that gets posted. If we now have to sift through the artificial crap as well this site is doomed. Yahoo! Answers here we come.

Comment: @Dom: You realize that by posting answers that you can't verify you are actually harming the community? I checked your answer to the WGSL question and your answer wasn't even in the right language...

Comment: I do realize this, and perhaps my account should be banned for the violations that I have committed. However, I believe that issue is of little importance when it is compared with the very real issue of many different users obscuring the responses generated by ChatGPT to gamify the system and ultimately ruin the quality of answers.

Comment: @Dom: How do you know [we weren't already aware of the issue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421778/238704)

Comment: For the record, mods have been trying to stay on top of it for now, but it's also not much of a secret that we don't have a whole lot of effective  tools to assist in detection of these answers. We mods are trying our best to stay on top of them, but as chatgpt gets more popular, we'll rely more and more on flags to detect users abusing it, and people not deciding to dump those answers to test the response (i.e. generating an artificial load when we could've spent time dealing with other users doing this, or other problems). We're doing our best as far as resources allow in the meanwhile

Comment: Well, I cannot do anything but apologize. I already understand the time and resources that I have wasted and there can be nothing else that comes out of this conversation than to highlight my ignorance, laziness, and selfishness. As @PresidentJamesK.Polk has already pointed out, the issue has since been addressed. The hope is that maybe the prominence of the problem overflowing beyond manual moderation will prompt software to become developed to detect or flag these responses.

Comment: “Is there an answer-ban like there is a question-ban?” - Yes; Any answer that doesn’t meet the minimum quality expectations should be downvoted or flagged for a moderator to deal with. Looks like all their answers were already nuked

Comment: Similar? https://stackoverflow.com/users/19192614/boatti, https://stackoverflow.com/users/20684429/a-s, https://stackoverflow.com/users/20677565/kan-jang

Comment: If the answers are correct then who cares. This community trashes people that give reasonable answers. What do you think they'll do to bots who provide bad answers? This site isn't here for stroking everyone's ego over fairness. It's about making sure that people learn and get the answers they need. Do you really think AI won't eventually replace us here anyway?

Comment: @DotNetRussell Many of the answers *aren't* correct even if they look reasonable at a glance to someone unfamiliar with the subject, which is the problem. We might not be far off from AI being able to correctly answer questions as good as subject matter experts, but we're not there yet - and until then, better to keep the site clean of answers that the one posting may not even understand, let alone validate the correctness of.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think your assertion that many of the answers are incorrect, is in fact incorrect. Even if they are incorrect, once again, there's a mechanism in place already. This community is its own white blood cell system. Bad answers will be thrashed and flamed just like anyone else

Comment: @DotNetRussell If the answers were correct and the user followed the [referencing requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing), then that would be OK. The problem is that a high percentage of the answers are wrong/bad, but the bot is able to make the text look like it *might be* correct. The bot *doesn't care* about being correct. The bot has *nothing* in its design that even *attempts* to be correct. It just produces text that looks like it *might* be correct and *sometimes* it gets lucky and is correct.

Comment: @Makyen if the answer is incorrect, go downvote it. I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @DotNetRussell [It wastes everyone's time because the answers look plausible at first glance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384359/188189) It takes a lot of effort to realise they need to be downvoted. On top of that someone can create lots of answers very quickly over lots of different subject areas that then need lots of clean up/downvoting.

Comment: @DotNetRussell That would be the ideal. The real problem is that with many people posting these as fast as they can they can post them faster and in more volume than SO has available curation resources, if handled on a individual post basis. And by as fast as they can, there have been *multiple* people posing these at their maximum answer rate limit of 1 every 3 or 5 minutes. I've, personally, deleted about 500 of them, *just today*, so far and I expect that to be much higher later.

Comment: Once again, humans use this site. Humans are infinitely more incorrect than any of those AI models. The community somehow manages to weed those posts out without issue. Never mind the fact that all of stack overflow has at least 2 different types of modern captchas in place that prevent actual bots from posting unchecked. It still requires human interaction. I still don't see a problem with augmented humans here

Comment: Complicating that is that the bot is sufficiently good at making the text look good and sound good, without being correct, such that it often takes a significant amount of subject matter expertise to be able to know the answer is incorrect (without putting out the work to *try* the answer's solution). We just don't have enough people (regular users) willing and able to downvote and delete-vote to handle the influx, if we're handling them on an individual post basis. That doesn't even consider that a lot of the bad ones get upvoted, because they *look* good.

Comment: @DotNetRussell You appear to have completely glossed over the *posting rate issue* and the comparative amount of time and effort necessary to identify a typical bad post from the AI (may take an expert in the tech some time) vs a typical bad post from a human (typically obvious to most people in seconds). Unaugmented humans can't create a thousand words of a good looking, good sounding answer at a rate of 1 every 3 minutes for hours.

Comment: The site has a fairly static amount of users performing curation activities. That level was *already* substantially below what would really be needed to keep the site clean. We *can't* reasonably increase the available curation resources. Thus, *substantially* increasing the *need* for those resources, *is* going to have a significant negative effect.

Comment: ["_Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541).

Comment: Does this mean that we now need an AI to detect bad answers that were generated by an AI?

Comment: Update: in [the staff announcement on their ChatGPT policy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421991/11107541), for users with <125rep, their answering rate-limit is now 30 minutes (was 3). This change is also explained [in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering-limit).

Comment: This might not be a very good idea, @starball, because, it might make the account playing with that harder to detect and flag.

Comment: @Camion I can't change that and I had no involvement in that decision. You're better off posting that as a question post here on MSO. If you want to dialogue with the staff and community about it.