# Query/overrule a moderator decision that might be misguided, or at least is very opaque

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

This is in regard to this question: [Coldfusion DirectoryList Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74682528/coldfusion-directorylist-filter), and the answer for it by Boatti that has been deleted.

Moderator Martijn Pieters has deleted the answer to this question, and neglected to supply a reason (which in itself is poor form).

I can see nothing about the answer that would violate Stack Overflow's T&Cs, what's more it's a reasonable answer to the question concerned.

I tried to vote for the answer to be reinstated, but I cannot because Martijn is a moderator.

It would be good if even a moderator could explain why they are deleting material that other Stack Exchange community members have taken the time to create. That would be the civil and professional thing to do, yeah?

Anyway, can we get the answer undeleted / re-evaluated, or an explanation of why it was deleted? I want to get the original questioner moving on, and as my own answer would be similar to Boatti's I don't want that deleted for some opaque reason too.

Comment: That user spammed the site with around 60 AI generated answers over a period of 5 hours. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned

Comment: Gotcha. The AI got the answer largely right in this case, so... [shrug], what's the harm? Or was it a blanket "delete all this user's answers whether or not they're actually good ones" thing?

Comment: Looking at the user profile: _"This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends in 7 days."_ That should give you an hint.

Comment: Just because it's "Largely right" doesn't make it a good answer.

Comment: Saves reviewing all 60 of their answers, since ChatGPT seems to have a decent rate of outright wrong answers and even contradicting itself. The user hasn't done their due diligence checking them (as evidence by the high rate of answers), why should the burden be thrown on the community?

Comment: @AdamCameron Because there are plenty of answers which aren't even close to being largely right. Some aren't even in the correct programming language. But even if we were assume these are good answers, what's the point in having them on SO when users can generate the answers themselves on the fly?

Comment: Yeah, fair cop re not eyeballing all 60. "Largely right" would make the answer higher quality than a lot of the answers on here, yeah ;-). In this case I'm a subject material expert, and the answer is fine. lastly I'd say if an AI can answer a question well, then who cares if it's an AI doing it? The raison d'etre here is to get questions answered, right? Are we in the position for someone to actually add an _answer_ to this, and... move on? Cheers for the feedback.

Comment: Honestly, I'd guess the outcome wouldn't be like this (temporary) blanket ban if the users had been more responsible on using the AI by cross-checking it, and not claiming as their own writing or even their own idea... just because of quick rep.

Comment: Problem with AI generated answers is that huge number of them will be incorrect while looking like a good answer (elaborately written). Common poor answer written by people usually lack explanation and so they are more easily detected. Also if we let AI generated answer then everyone will start writing them and the sheer number of such mostly incorrect answers will suffocate the site. For the sake of few answers that might be correct we cannot allow this. Incorrect answers waste everyone's time.

Comment: OR. You are mistaken, because you can't see what a moderator like Martijn can see. Don't write meta posts toned as if there is no way you can be wrong.

Comment: I don't think I did that, Gimby, and sorry if I did give you that impression. I was asking for clarity (and suggesting clarity in the first place might've negated the need to ask). I'd be interested in the downvotes here, btw. Given I got good engagement from the comments, *and* this is the mechanism Stack Overflow suggests for making this line of questioning, how could I have improved the question?

Comment: "the civil and professional thing to do" is to presume that people have acted in a civil and professional way & not jump to unjustified conclusions in ignorance of the particular situation & the site rules.

Comment: Meta up/down vote reasons include agreement/disagreement with a post proposal or premise.

Comment: This question jumps to the conclusion that the mod is wrong, in the title: _"Overrule, misguided"_. Then it asserts the mod failed to supply a reason they're not even allowed to supply, and indirectly calls the moderator (by name) uncivil and unprofessional. That's why you got my downvote. I assume other users may have similar reasoning.

Comment: This question does not jump to a conclusion that the mod is wrong. Op is clearly confused as to why something was deleted. The mod who deleted it provided no reason. So they ask why it was deleted here and get downvoted to oblivion, everyone piling on them like they have committed some great offense, but where else can they ask the question? Why is nobody addressing the mod failure to give a reason?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The AI consistently writes **bad answers that look good**.
Just because they hit the mark every now and then doesn't mean we should just allow the bot.

As stated before, users are using the bot to post a *large* volume of answers, without fact-checking them. We can't expect the mod team to fact-check everything, so the only real option there is to just remove all of it.

Think of it this way:

If a *user* consistently writes poor answers, with the occasional correct one, they get an answer ban.
ChatGPT just got an answer ban. The bot can't use its users any more to answer.

Comment: I personally side with eventually allowing AI, but the current large influx of answers, incomplete rules, and users completely disregarding factual accuracy and preferring quantity over quality is very concerning, and definitely worth temporarily banning it over. Even prior to the blanket ban, the policy was that [they're okay](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/412696/6296561), but are treated as answers copied from any source on the internet (which is what Martijn used to deal with the answer; AI-generated + no source = deletion).

Comment: But yeah, you're right. It's effectively an answer ban while we're sorting stuff out. There's probably going to be more discussions in the upcoming days and weeks to sort everything out, while we mods  (and possibly the community at large) figure out how we deal with the bad answers, at least if the consensus is to allow it in the long run

Comment: Cheers @Cerberus: makes sense. I guess the missing bit was perhaps the automated closing of the answer (legit, as it turns out) could also automatically add an explanatory comment, then the situation would not have been so opaque? Anyhow, not a big deal. Appreciate the clear answer (from you and a lot of of the commenters).

Comment: Current AI can't write good code answers. I don't see that happening in the coming few years. GitHub Copilot, for example, more often than not misses the mark, and that's an AI specialized in code. In regards to the opacity, @Adam, There is no way to add a note like that to a answer deletion. And as suspension reasons are private, adding a comment stating _"This answer was deleted because OP broke rule X"_ breaks that privacy.

Comment: As an aside, adding that comment to every answer we delete at the moment is a massive addition to moderator workload. We're looking at upwards of thousands of deletions per day atm. Adding a comment to all of them just to appease 10k users who don't follow what's going on is an excessive amount of work for little benefit. OP is always informed when we delete answers over AI-related reasons, so it's just for 10k users at this point

Comment: @Zoe cool yeah. I kind of imagined that if there was a "bulk change" option, then "provide a comment with the bulk change" might also be a thing. I do not have visibility of the tooling in question, so was simply speculating that it would be useful for the gen. pop. ppl like me who have only "it's been deleted" to go on (hence this question in the first place). Even the ChatGPT thing mentioned in the "closed /duplicate" note on this is not immediately apparent as being the reason _from where I sit_, out in the gen. pop. I do appreciate all the clarifications.

Comment: To clarify, the only bulk deletion tooling that exists is for comments. Sadly. Mass-deleting questions or answers is a chore of ctrl-click, md<cr><c-w> (in any grouping order). Any additional actions are done uniquely, though often with the help of tools created by ourselves because we have garbage tooling in the first place

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the peek inside the sausage factory ;-)

Comment: Ultimately the user is responsible for what CGPT generates, if that content for match our quality expectations, then it will be generated. If they submit dozens of low quality answers, then they should be treated as any user who submitted massive amounts of low quality content, regardless if some of that content was higher quality than the rest of their incorrect low quality contributions. BLUF: If you submit 60 answers, regardless of how it was generated, expect some eyebrows to be raised.