# Can I use code that was mostly auto-completed by GitHub Copilot?

Tags: discussion

If the code I was using to answer a question was for the most part auto-completed by GitHub Copilot, then I couldn't know if it was using open source code or not, so I couldn't attribute the original developer.

I am aware that this may be a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412696/is-it-acceptable-to-post-answers-generated-by-an-ai-such-as-github-copilot), but I think the answer is outdated when you take into consideration the [new temporary policy about AI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: you can find attribution for the code it generate. Remember, this is just mutating input that it was trained on, and output things based on comments of the code. Case in point: https://twitter.com/docsparse/status/1581461734665367554?s=46&t=yF5zaMKk62GD32GddpVd2Q

Answer (score 21):

[If you're not confident in your ability to license it, you can't confidently publish it.](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)

Put another way, if you don't own the content you're publishing, you shouldn't publish it.