# Are employees of collectives exempt from site-wide conventions?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, collectives

When going through the First Questions queue I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396556/how-do-i-access-a-users-firebase-uid-on-user-creation-in-javascript) (question has been deleted, see the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20221111151759/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396556/how-do-i-access-a-users-firebase-uid-on-user-creation-in-javascript) for <10k rep users). It contains an image of code, so I cast my close vote. I saw it had one answer and I was surprised to see that it was from a 527k rep user who was an employee of the Google Cloud Collective.

As [this meta answer advises](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412668/13376511), questions with images of code, or even any very low-quality questions, should not be answered. So, I am confused about why a user with such high rep thought this was an acceptable question to answer. Is it a different situation because the question is in a collective and the user is an employee, or do the same conventions apply regardless of whether or not the question is in a collective?

Comment: In fairness, the person who answered added a comment discouraging them from using an image of code.

Comment: Related: [Microsoft Azure Customer Engineers Giving Low Quality Answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419331)

Comment: The problem with that, though, @AndrewGrimm, is that it's now "too late"; the OP has their answer and can disappear into the nether, never to fix their question. Users should be encouraged to fix their questions *before* they are answered; if they can get an answer regardless of posting code as text, why would they bother changing a bad habit?

Comment: Entirely aside from collectives, a 528k rep user who's been a member for 13 years should probably know not to answer questions with code as images.

Comment: There are even review queue audits with code pictures that have to be 'looks ok' from audit point of view (even a comment let's you fail the audit). So I guess that item isn't strict.

Comment: Why are you surprised by the reputation and the behaviour? You don't get 528k reputation by closing questions, so I'm not surprised those questions get answers instead.

Answer (score 62):

If Collectives want their own rules, they can migrate to teams and have all the fun they want.

If you post on Stack Overflow proper, be it in the context of a collective or not, your post has to follow community guidelines and your post is subject to the same curation and moderation as any other post. Being associated with a Collective is not a free pass, (n)ever.

Answer (score 41):

You're right that questions containing only images of code should not be answered, but closed until the OP edits the question to satisfy the requirements.

Members/employees of a collective are absolutely *not* exempt from any of the requirements on the site. For that matter, neither are site moderators or staff or anyone else. The same rules/requirements/conventions apply to everyone when it comes to posting content on the site.

There are several reasons for why users answer questions that need to be fixed:

- In many cases, users are simply unaware of the rules/conventions regarding posting content and feel that questions should be answered even if they are unclear, need debugging information, or even if they're off-topic.
- Often, users get satisfaction from helping out another user by answering their question. While this can actively hurt the site's goal of building a Q&A repository that is useful to *others*, I certainly understand the feeling of wanting to be helpful.
- In some cases, users just want to earn reputation/badges/etc from answering questions, and tend not to pay attention to whether the question meets the site guidelines.

---

I should also point out that the sentiment "*So, I am confused about why a user with such high rep thought this was an acceptable question to answer*" makes the flawed assumption that high reputation score correlates with a strong understanding of the site culture. This is unfortunately not true, and many high rep users have similar misunderstandings of the site's purpose as low rep users have.

Comment: I like this because it addresses the _actual_ problem, which really has nothing to do with Collectives. I mean I'm not a fan of the Collectives feature myself, but we don't have to make every bad thing about it.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment here. However I'd add that some high-rep users have a quarrel with aspects of the site's culture, and they insist on doing their own thing. Wilful/stylistic misspellings, chatty material that is not technical writing, woeful over-formatting, encouraging terrible questions, asking counter-questions / starting discussions in answers, etc - I've seen it all. Mostly this crowd knows their posting style isn't always terrible enough to involve a moderator, and thus their systemic errors largely become uneditable.

Comment: (FWIW I would not include this particular high-rep user in that category - I have always found them to be amenable to conversation and suggestion).

Answer (score 1):

This particular case didn't actually need the code from the images to be solved.  User creation creates a promise with a known value that anyone with the knowledge of the returned value can answer.

While I agree members of collectives (or any other sub-group of users) should receive no special treatment for being members of such group... I don't think the question being used here was an example of that occurring.

Answer (score -23):

Yes, I agree with your point.

Someone with that reputation should have improved the question first. And then they should have answered it.

Seniors with enough reputation can edit the question and improve the question in case the question is worth an edit.

For [Firebase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebase), this question is not a duplicate and then editing will add one more useful question /answer to the site.

FYI: I have edited the question and now it should be fine. I know the languages JavaScript and Firebase, so I did the edit. If you do not know, you should avoid editing.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you took to transcribe the image of code, but please see [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) for the various issues related to doing that.

Comment: I think about helping new comer! Yes, we should not do that with respect to discussion; I know JS and firebase so did that, else would have skipped it for sure..  Also added comment below question for user for [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can't guarantee you make your transcription identical, @MarmiK . You could introduce errors, remove them, or inadvertently change the code. The only person who can change an image of code to text is the OP, by then copied and pasting their code from their IDE.

Comment: It's good you want to help new users, but life's too short to transcribe code to text anyway, you'll be here all year if you try do it to all posts. Just vote to close, downvote and move on, and you'll be helping many more new users in the future by keeping the site clean and easy to find high quality questions and answers.

Comment: Not only is this a waste of time, your hard work is likely to be lost when other users rightly revert these kinds of edits. OP, and only OP, should be replacing images of code with proper code blocks. Transcribing other users' posts also encourages them to _continue_ posting images of code, rather than learning how to use the site properly.

Comment: For transparency, I did infact revert the edit some hours ago, as @Chris suggested would happen. If for no other reason than, infact, the image *did not* replicate the OP's code, as an extra brace (`}`) was added the the transcribed code (this isn't, of course, the only reason).

Comment: @Larnu even though I agree with you about not transcribing the code for the op, why do you think that marmik can't "guarantee" that the transcription is identical?

Comment: See the linked question already in the comments, @Lamak. My answer there explains all.