# Poor questions should not be answered by people with high reps. Why are they?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came across this meta post : [Should one answer terribly poor questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293931/22390653) and thought answering poor questions are not the norm, at least among people with high reps. But then these are counter-examples:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

```sql
SELECT TOP 30
  Score,
  Id AS [Post Link],
  CreationDate
FROM Posts
WHERE Score < -5 and AnswerCount > 0
ORDER BY CreationDate desc
```

*(You may need to click a few before you land on a question with an answer from higher rep user)*

Although most of these questions are closed (for being flagged I'm guessing), it is safe to assume the person answering did not raise the flag, otherwise they would not add an answer.

So why would someone with >6k rep answer a poor question? Is there a reason behind it or just exceptions?

As to why I think they shouldn't, I think it is better explained by @Denilson Amorim from the mentioned meta post.

I want to clarify that I completely agree that no harm is being done by adding an answer to SO, regardless of the question quality. However there are plenty of examples where poor questions are closed before an answer (and thus disabling answering). Since high rep contributors have higher privileges, **they *should* flag / close instead of answering.**

I do not want to smear the good names of those who have answered poor questions. Removed direct links to questions and replaced with query

Defn. of a poor question: See the answer for [What is a "BAD" question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67960/what-is-a-bad-question)

In my opinion, **I think a high rep (thereby expert) users of the platform should be able to detect a poor question without guidance**. This is not to say they don't, but they should not wait on other community members with enough rep to downvote the question to know that it was bad.

Comment: Additionally I think adding a comment to a poor question is the right way.

Comment: I have noticed this same phenomenon and it used to bother me, but then I noticed something else: most of the answers from high-rep users to poor questions were *excellent* answers. So then the overarching question is: does that question/answer combo add value to the site or detract from the site's value? It depends of course on the actual specific question but I often found my answer was "yes".

Comment: Some people have high rep _because_ they answer questions indiscriminately.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you are right of course, they are inevitably good/excellent answers. But I argue that I cannot (do not) search by answers but I do search by questions. It should (somehow) affect the site

Comment: @khelwood This might be the reason, albeit their answers for these questions are not the highest upvoted ones in their profiles.

Comment: No, because such users can, and do, answer clear and well asked questions too, @PatioFurnitureIsCool . Those answers get plenty of views and thus  votes, however, because (some) such users *also* answer many unclear questions, and get maybe a single accept or upvote on them, that reputation does also pile up.

Comment: Downvote the question and ignore the answer. If there's a good and clear close reason, vote to close. Then sit back and wait for community curation or the roomba to clean up. If a really good answer saves the question from deletion, I see that as a win.

Comment: @ThomA That may not be relevant, as all the links in my post are fairly recent, and people answering them should already have a lot of reps. My question is why would they answer instead of flagging / adding a comment?

Comment: @user4581301 my question is more geared to as `why high rep community does this`? I understand there is `no harm no foul`, and I am actually not making a request / additional feature to stop people from answering poor questions.

Comment: I'd suspect they each have their own reasons, ranging from purely selfish in wanting rep, to just wanting to help people who need help.

Comment: But seriously, if their answers keep getting deleted along with the weak questions, the profit motive goes away.

Comment: @user4581301 they typically don't get deleted, due to receiving upvotes.

Comment: Roomba won't kill a question with upvoted answers, but I'm pretty sure I've seen upvoted answers deleted by the community along with the question that spawned them.

Comment: to does happen, it's just rare because it requires 3 votes from a very small pool of users with enough rep.

Comment: You have the right to downvote any question / answer you think deserves a downvote. I would often downvote answers to clear duplicate / outright bad questions when I was still active.

Comment: In the end the only answer is: we don't know. Any guess probably tells more about the guesser than about the answerer.

Comment: "I want to clarify that I completely agree that no harm is being done by adding an answer to SO, regardless of the question quality." - The communities ability to handle a question with an answer is different than a question without an answer.  Users answering questions, that are extremely low quality and ultimately likely submitting low quality answers for that reason, actually do harm the community in many ways.

Comment: @SecurityHound while your premise is correct (and sharing mine), as others pointed out to me that the answers given under those poor question by high rep users are quality answers, not poor ones. It in fact does not help make my point of not answering, but I do recognize that good answers have merit.

Comment: Its an asininely practice they perform to raise their rep quickly and continunously rather than do the search for a duplicate and let someone else get the credit they deserve, that's been my experience with most high rep users on this site sadly.  generalization absolutely and i apologize to those who don't but most of my encounters have been negative.  I hunt for questions to answer an answer them well, and usually some high rep guy slides in and steals all the thunder because "oooh high rep he must be right"

Comment: Those answers shouldnt be given and only pollute the site with MORE duplicate answers and reward BAD questions with answers. why will they follow the rules for asking a good question when you answer their question anyways?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk "most of the answers from high-rep users to poor questions were *excellent* answers" No argument there, but I feel this is related to the [Fastest Gun in the West problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem). Several years ago I remember reading a high-rep user saying they had a collection of pre-made answers that could quickly be quickly tweaked for common questions. I don't know how common the practice is though (and I know it's essentially an anecdote without a source)

Comment: [Related.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348705/is-the-how-to-answer-articles-section-on-only-answering-well-asked-questions-ad)

Comment: When I'm searching for answers, I'm not concerned with the phrasing of the question, just the topic. A lot of clarity is found in some of the responses to "poor quality questions" (which is extremely subjective). I book mark the answers. If you want to improve the community, maybe help improve the questions being asked instead. This seems like a disingenuous complaint, and its personal to boot.

Comment: @MeghanM. I suggest you read through [whats-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) so that you can understand the point of this post.

Comment: "_There are naive questions, tedious questions, ill-phrased questions, questions put after inadequate self-criticism. But every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question._” -- Carl Sagan

Comment: @Fe2O3 *... and then there are [100k emails per week that just can't wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)*. -- Sun Tzu

Comment: 167K views and 679 UV's on the leading answer... What is it that you wish to point out citing that example? One can only _guess_ that 146 people thought this would lead to more spam emails... Who's to say?

Comment: @Fe2O3 The point I am trying to make is your quote is inconsequential to this discussion. Poor question is downvoted for a reason, it is of poor quality. This is not subjective, a plethora of meta posts and [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) has long established what is considered a good question. Citing Carl Sagan / saying there is no dumb question means you are not familiar with SO

Comment: I think your post is in need of clarification/quantification of what a "poor question" is. Score alone isn't a direct measure of quality, per se. Are you referring to questions that are of such poor quality that anyone with two brain cells they could rub together could see it's ***totally unanswerable*** and ***unsalvageable***, or is it possible the first few readers didn't fully grok the question and down voted, and later a higher-rep user *was* able to parse through the noise to understand the issue and provide an answer (*and hopefully edited the post into better shape*)?

Comment: Just this past week, in my interest group, I've requested that two questions to be reopened. The hi-rep user(s) who'd closed the question seemingly did not _grok_ the OP's predicament/perplexity. When re-opened, a satisfactory answer could be given. In an ideal world human beings would always think alike and follow _guidelines_. This is not an ideal world. Sagan's view reflects the purpose of Q&A in our heterogeneous reality.

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated my post. Please let me know whether you have a response now that it is.

Comment: @DrewReese `Score alone isn't a direct measure of quality` this might be true in some sense, but not reflective of how reps work in SO. Downvote means `This question does not show research effort... not useful`, this is the literal tooltip when you press downvote (ofc there is flagging, I am a fan of flagging and am recommending it over answering).

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you want to know here. If a question is *answerable* (*e.g. not a duplicate, able to be understood, etc*), the answerer's rep is irrelevant. People vote for all kinds of weird, odd, and "stupid" reasons. I'm just as dumbfounded coming across questions with -3 score that are perfectly answerable as I am coming across obviously "bad/poor" questions that already have +3 score.

Comment: @DrewReese `People vote for all kinds of weird, odd, and "stupid" reasons.` I think I have my answer. What I wanted to know was whether people (particularly high privileged/mod-candidate) have reasons for answering poor questions instead of just closing them, I guess the answer is `no one knows why they do things :)`. I say this with all due respect ofc. So far it (ansing poor q) looked like an encouragement from an answerer's part. I now think it's not.

Comment: "You may need to click a few before you land on a question with an answer from higher rep user" - it should be possible to enhance the query to filter for this. Also, if you actually tried the query that you show, you should be able to obtain a perma-link for it to share with us - and SEDE will automatically cache the result for a week or so.

Comment: It is the duality of Stack Overflow I'd say. It promotes gamification through the reputation, privilege and badge system, but at the same time demands that people not answer any and all easy questions (repeatedly probably) which are very likely to be duplicates in a large pool of duplicates or simply off-topic but otherwise perfectly answerable. Besides that, many people visiting this site really have an intention to *help out* and that kind of conflicts with the greater goal, which is to create a repository of knowledge with which many people can *help themselves*. Content over people.

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool the real reason is that answering is *far easier* than moderation and there are rewards for answering vs. "you are *<censored> downtroding elitist* commenting/editing/voting/closing my awesome completely clear question" rewards for moderation attempts.

Comment: I'm #25 in all-time rep, and often accused of answering bad questions. I don't do it for the additional rep, I do it because if I can understand the question I consider it "good enough" and I like to help people. Long before SO I made my reputation on Usenet by being able to interpret the questions from people who have trouble expressing themselves.

Comment: @Barmar: But only after an exhaustive duplicate search, right? Or is [FGITW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533) in the way?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Usually I try to find a dup. Some topics are hard to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The premises of [the first MSO question you linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293931/11107541) are problematic. I wrote [an answer post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426359/11107541) to hopefully address some of the problems. I suggest you give that a read.

In terms of the problem of users answering poor questions (as in- questions that should be closed), probably a lot of this can be chalked up to incentive design and rough edges in system-cleanup design. Getting an accepted answer gives more rep (15) than a regular upvote (10), and there are no reputation or badge incentives for closing things. There are [several proposals for rep incentives for dup-closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/387398/997587) (incentive design for this is kind of hard, but I think it's worth thinking about), and badges for close-voting in general have been declined (there are review queue badges instead). An answer getting accepted prevents [auto-deletion](/help/roomba), which means slow manual deletion (if ever), and rep ends up kept even for something that is closed or should be closed and deleted (there are also proposals that rep gain on closed questions not be kept even if the Q/A is not deleted).

---

I went through several of the questions you've answered and found

- [Horizontal printing and scaling in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77056300/11107541) rather poorly titled, pretty localized goal
- [Trying to grab highest and lowest non-zero or below from int input but negative int keeps getting passed into output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77055173/11107541) "my code is not working. help!"
- [How can I find the time complexity of this algorithm (backtracking)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77026844/11107541) very poorly titled
- [Python throws an AttributeError: module 'qrtools' has no attribute 'QR' for a valid attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77026993/11107541) closed as "needs debugging details"
- [Python3: HowTo align the formatted output of values from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77025508/11107541) title could probably be better
- [Type hint for a matplotlib color?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76973907/11107541) fine(?)
- [how to generate array based on 2 other arrays using numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76956059/11107541) very poorly titled, pretty localized goal, "I tried X and something went wrong but I don't know what" <no further elaboration on observations and expected outcome from their attempt>
- [Filtering the value using java 8 map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76926962/11107541) rather poorly titled, not a very minimal MRE.
- [Java-- do-while loop jumping to next iteration without checking exit condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76926452/11107541) "my code not work!" at a quick glance, not a bad job of describing the problem and shows some isolation effort (problem definition effort)
- [Why empty list to function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76925751/11107541) poor title
- [How can I execute my except ValueError when I use a letter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76919286/11107541) poor title, code dump with no description of the goal / expected behaviour / what the code is supposed to do
- [Individually accessing each element inside a div with Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76917621/11107541) either a canonical exists, or a better one can be written, or the question can be edited into better shape
- [Why does slice() not work when the first index is negative and the second is positive, but the opposite does?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76917637/11107541) closed as duplicate
- [star pattern to make a hollow butterfly in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76907395/11107541) pretty localized goal "my code not work!"
- [How to select rows based on column value of csv file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76904320/11107541) closed as duplicate
- [Questions about StringBuilder Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76902678/11107541) terrible title

Poor titles and "help me fix my code" are not close-worthy, but they do tend to be low-value in the long term. Poor titles make for harder searching (search bar, google, other search engine, etc.). Questions about code not behaving as intended tend to be pretty poorly isolated / minimized in my experience, which makes them less "relatable". The more you isolate causes, the closer you will get to the core issue, and the more people who will probably find the Q&A valuable. In my experience, poor titles and localized issues combined together make for incredibly frustrating red-herrings in search results.

I'd suggest you

- Give a bit more attention to searching for duplicate targets (doing so is in your best interest if you want rep anyway: answer the canonical, and if your answer is useful, you'll get rep- and probably more than from answering duplicates)
- Spend some time improving questions (those that are not close-worthy) that you spend your time answering. This is also in your best interest. For example, give a more appropriately descriptive, more easily searchable title. The Q&A will probably get more views from people with the same question, and that'll mean more people your answer possibly helps.

Comment: `In terms of the problem of users answering poor questions, probably a lot of this can be chalked up to incentive design` this is (probably accurately) answers my question to the point.

Comment: One other thing was pointed out in the sea of comments below my post, that up/down voting of a question may not be as reliable as it is designed to be. That is also a system wide issue if it was a system wide practice. Not sure if it is.

Answer (score 4):

It can have a very wide range of explanations. Every user is an individual. And the explanation may be as simple as that they didn't think it was a poor question. Some of the questions that pops up from your query have both upvotes and downvotes.

> I want to clarify that I completely agree that no harm is being done by adding an answer to SO, regardless of the question quality.

Strictly not true. Sure, the harm is not great, but one could reasonably argue that it adds noise, and noise makes good stuff harder to find. That's a kind of harm. It also makes moderation harder, also a kind of harm. Not great, but not zero.

Comment: `Some of the questions that pops up from your query have both upvotes and downvotes.` I see. I actually can't see individual votes. But I guess the point made it across since your take seems to be high rep users should not add noise.

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool Seing vote counts is a privilege you get when you hit 1k. No one should add noise, but people have different definition of noise. :)

Comment: I agree, but a poor question is not subjective. I am finger-crossed over here so that this discussion does not veer away from questions :), because once that bridge is crossed everything is at OP's, mod's and community's discretion. One thing that is not subjective is good question and good answer (not upvoted, just good).

Comment: @PatioFurnitureIsCool The only way to sensibly define a question as "good" in an objective way is to use measurable metrics, like score and views. But sure, there are questions where *most* people would agree that it's bad. Note the word *most*. It does not mean "all". So it might be that 99 of 100 agrees that the question is bad and the last 100th person is the one who answers. :)
But then again, that's only one of many possible reasons.